# How to create query parameters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, urlencode

Is there any way to create the *query parameters* for doing a *GET request* in JavaScript?

Just like in Python you have [`urllib.urlencode()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20080926234926/http://docs.python.org:80/lib/module-urllib.html), which takes in a dictionary (or list of two tuples) and creates a string like `'var1=value1&var2=value2'`.

Comment: Reverse question: [url - How can I get query string values in JavaScript? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function encodeQueryData(data) {
   const ret = [];
   for (let d in data)
     ret.push(encodeURIComponent(d) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[d]));
   return ret.join('&');
}
```

Usage:

```
const data = { 'first name': 'George', 'last name': 'Jetson', 'age': 110 };
const querystring = encodeQueryData(data);
```

Comment: When iterating with `for`, use [hasOwnProperty](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to ensure interoperability.

Comment: @troelskn, good point... although in this case, someone would have to be extending Object.prototype to break it, which is a pretty bad idea to start with.

Comment: @Shog9 Why is it a bad ideia?

Comment: @Cesar, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832617/what-are-the-benefits-and-dangers-of-adding-methods-to-object-prototype-in-javasc**

Comment: Downvote because I have no idea whether this solution acts according to the specification and will always work. Prefer the standard URLSearchParams that is now available. OP please consider retreating this outdated answer.

Comment: this is insufficient. `encodeQueryData({foo:{bar:123}})` returns `foo=%5Bobject%20Object%5D` , but the correct return value would be  `foo%5Bbar%5D=123`

Comment: This is the new correct way.
`function encodeQueryData(data) {
  return new URLSearchParams(data).toString();
}`

Answer (score 262):

[URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) has increasing browser support.

```
const data = {
  var1: 'value1',
  var2: 'value2'
};

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(data);

// searchParams.toString() === 'var1=value1&var2=value2'
```

Node.js offers the [querystring](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) module.

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

const data = {
  var1: 'value1',
  var2: 'value2'
};

const searchParams = querystring.stringify(data);

// searchParams === 'var1=value1&var2=value2'
```

Comment: Definitely the clean and modern approach. You can also later freely call `searchParams.append(otherData)`

Comment: URLSearchParams will parse White space as '+' instead of '%20'. For example, `new URLSearchParams({ abc: 'a b c' }).toString()`result in `'abc=a+b+c'`

Comment: How is it that in 2021 there is not a more standardized way of achieving this? For example, what about adding `?` only when `searchParams` are not blank.

Answer (score 83):

**functional**

```
function encodeData(data) {
    return Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
        return [key, data[key]].map(encodeURIComponent).join("=");
    }).join("&");
}
```

Comment: Nice one! .map() has been implemented in JavaScript 1.6 so almost all browsers, even the granny ones support it. But as you can guess IE does not except IE 9+. But do not worry, there is a workaround. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility

Comment: `var data = { bloop1: true, bloop2: "something" };
var url = "https://something.com/?";
var params = encodeData(data);
var finalUrl = url + params; // Is this the right use?` Should produce `https://www.something.com/?bloop1=true&bloop2=something` ?

Comment: @DylanHunt: Yup…

Comment: this is insufficient. `encodeData({foo:{bar:123}})` returns `foo=%5Bobject%20Object%5D` , but the correct return value would be `foo%5Bbar%5D=123`

Answer (score 42):

[Zabba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/382818/zabba) has provided in a comment on the currently accepted answer a suggestion that to me is the best solution: use [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

If I use `jQuery.param()` on the data in the original question, then the code is simply:

```
const params = jQuery.param({
    var1: 'value',
    var2: 'value'
});
```

The variable `params` will be

```
"var1=value&var2=value"
```

For more complicated examples, inputs and outputs, see the [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) documentation.

Answer (score 29):

The built-in `URL` class provides a convenient interface for creating and parsing URLs.

There are no networking methods that require exactly a `URL` object, strings are good enough. So technically we don’t have to use `URL`. But sometimes it can be really helpful.

Example

```js
let url = new URL("https://google.com/search");
url.searchParams.set('var1', "value1");
url.searchParams.set('var2', "value2");
url.searchParams.set('var3', "value3");
url.searchParams.set('var4', "value4 has spaces");

console.log(url)
```

Comment: I was scrolling searching for this one.

Comment: Don't forget to convert `url` object to string with `url.toString()`

Comment: `const url = new URL("/some-route");` throws "'URL': Invalid URL" error.

Answer (score 15):

### ES2017 (ES8)

Making use of [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), which returns an array of object's `[key, value]` pairs. For example, for `{a: 1, b: 2}` it would return `[['a', 1], ['b', 2]]`. It is not supported (and won't be) only by IE.

#### Code:

```
const buildURLQuery = obj =>
      Object.entries(obj)
            .map(pair => pair.map(encodeURIComponent).join('='))
            .join('&');
```

#### Example:

```
buildURLQuery({name: 'John', gender: 'male'});
```

#### Result:

```
"name=John&gender=male"
```

Answer (score 10):

We've just released [arg.js](https://github.com/stretchr/arg.js), a project aimed at solving this problem once and for all.  It's traditionally been so difficult but now you can do:

```
var querystring = Arg.url({name: "Mat", state: "CO"});
```

And reading works:

```
var name = Arg("name");
```

or getting the whole lot:

```
var params = Arg.all();
```

and if you care about the difference between `?query=true` and `#hash=true` then you can use the `Arg.query()` and `Arg.hash()` methods.

Answer (score 9):

This should do the job:

```
const createQueryParams = params => 
      Object.keys(params)
            .map(k => `${k}=${encodeURI(params[k])}`)
            .join('&');
```

Example:

```
const params = { name : 'John', postcode: 'W1 2DL'}
const queryParams = createQueryParams(params)
```

Result:

```
name=John&postcode=W1%202DL
```

Comment: I've later realized that it's actually a slightly different version of @manav's response below. But anyway, it could still be preferable for ES6 syntax.

Comment: First of all, you are not encoding the keys. Also, you should use `encodeURIComponent()` instead of `encodeURI`. [Read about the difference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI#Description).

Answer (score 8):

If you are using [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org) there is [Form.serialize](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/form/serialize)

If you are using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) there is [Ajax/serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize)

I do not know of any independent functions to accomplish this, though, but a google search for it turned up some promising options if you aren't currently using a library. If you're not, though, you really should because they are heaven.

Comment: jQuery.param() takes object and transform it to GET query string (this function better matches the question).

Answer (score 3):

A little modification to typescript:

```
  public encodeData(data: any): string {
    return Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
      return [key, data[key]].map(encodeURIComponent).join("=");
    }).join("&");
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just like to revisit this almost 10 year old question. In this era of off-the-shelf programming, your best bet is to set your project up using a dependency manager (`npm`). There is an entire cottage industry of libraries out there that encode query strings and take care of all the edge cases. This is one of the more popular ones -

https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string

Comment: Very unspecific answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
const base = "https://www.facebook.com"
const path = '/v15.0/dialog/oauth'
const params = new URLSearchParams({
    client_id: clientID,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri,
    state: randomState,
})
const url = new URL(`${path}?${params.toString()}`, base)
```

Here's an example to create query parameters and build URL from base using only JavaScript built-in constructor.
This is part of Facebook Login implementation in manual approach.

According to [URLSearchParams doc's example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams#examples), there's a line

```
const new_url = new URL(`${url.origin}${url.pathname}?${new_params}`);
```

and I've followed that practice.

This is by far the most standardized way to build URL I believe.

I was a bit surprised that JavaScript doesn't supports `query` or `fragment` arguments in thier `URL` constructor still in 2023, despite It's definately worth having that.

Answer (score 2):

**Build URL with parameters in JavaScript**

*Construct URL without parameters*

`const apiEndPoint = new URL('https://geocode.maps.co/reverse');`

*Organise parameters in object form*

```
const parameters = {
    lat: 52.508,
    lon: 13.381
}
```

*Construct search parameters from object*

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(parameters)
```

*Add search parameters to URL*

```
apiEndPoint.search = searchParams
```

*Final URL*

```
const finalURL = apiEndPoint.toString()
```

*Print completed URL on console*

```
console.log(finalURL)
```

[Log] https://geocode.maps.co/reverse?lat=52.508&lon=13.381

Comment: How is this answer different from the most upvoted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
let my_url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com")
my_url.pathname = "/questions"

const parameters = {
    title: "just",
    body: 'test'
}

Object.entries(parameters).forEach(([name, value]) => my_url.searchParams.set(name, value))

console.log(my_url.href)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have improved the function of [shog9`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111545/13278378) to handle array values

```js
function encodeQueryData(data) {
    const ret = [];
    for (let d in data) {
        if (typeof data[d] === 'object' || typeof data[d] === 'array') {
            for (let arrD in data[d]) {
                ret.push(`${encodeURIComponent(d)}[]=${encodeURIComponent(data[d][arrD])}`)
            }
        } else if (typeof data[d] === 'null' || typeof data[d] === 'undefined') {
            ret.push(encodeURIComponent(d))
        } else {
            ret.push(`${encodeURIComponent(d)}=${encodeURIComponent(data[d])}`)
        }

    }
    return ret.join('&');
}
```

### Example

```js
let data = {
  user: 'Mark'
  fruits: ['apple', 'banana']
}

encodeQueryData(data) // user=Mark&fruits[]=apple&fruits[]=banana
```

Comment: this is an improvement, yes, but it's still insufficient: `encodeQueryData({foo:{bar:123}})` returns `foo[]=123` , but the correct return value would be `foo%5Bbar%5D=123`

Answer (score 0):

By using [queryencoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/queryencoder), you can have some nice-to-have options, such custom date formatters, nested objects and decide if a `val: true` will be just `value` or `value=true`.

```js
const { encode } = require('queryencoder');

const object = {
    date: new Date('1999-04-23')
};

// The result is 'date=1999-04-23'
const queryUrl = encode(object, {
    dateParser: date => date.toISOString().slice(0, 10)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly improved version that removes empty values from the result:

```
function createQueryParams (params) {
  return Object.keys(params).filter(k => params[k])
    .map(k => `${k}=${encodeURIComponent(params[k])}`)
    .join('&');
}
```

Answer (score -13):

This [thread](http://web.archive.org/web/20120407213044/http://www.phpbuilder.com:80/board/showthread.php?t=10318476) points to some code for escaping URLs in php.  There's `escape()` and `unescape()` which will do most of the work, but the you need add a couple extra things.

```
function urlencode(str) {
str = escape(str);
str = str.replace('+', '%2B');
str = str.replace('%20', '+');
str = str.replace('*', '%2A');
str = str.replace('/', '%2F');
str = str.replace('@', '%40');
return str;
}

function urldecode(str) {
str = str.replace('+', ' ');
str = unescape(str);
return str;
}
```

Comment: encodeURIComponent handles this and doesn't incorrectly use + for a space.