# How to use jquery to manipulate the querystring

Tags: jquery, url, query-string

I have a select dropdown with id's mapped to values. 
On the onChange event I want to redirect to the same url but with 'id=value' appended to the querystring.

How do I check that this 'id' option isn't already in the querystring (I don't want multiple values) and replace / append as necessary.

How do I check if '?' is already in the querystring and append to the url if its not.

Is there an easy way with jquery to do this?

It must do something similar under the hood for `$().ajax(url, {options})`  calls.
I was hoping I could just do `$().redirect( url, { id : $(this).val() })` or somesuch.

Thanks in advance.

Note: This page may or may not have a few different query options passed in (which set defaults on other form options) so replacing the whole querystring is not an option.

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <script>
    $(function(){                                                                                                                                         
        $('#selector').change(function(){                                                                                                                 
            // problem if 'id' option already exists
            var url = location.href + '?;id=' + $(this).val();                                                                                            
            location.assign( url );
        });                                                                                                                                               
    });                                                                                                                                                   
  </script>

  <a href="#" onclick="location.assign( location.pathname )">reset</a>                                                                                      
  <form>                                                                                                                                                    
    <select id='selector' name='id'>                                                                                                                      
        <option value='1'>one</option>                                                                                                                    
        <option value='2'>two</option>                                                                                                                    
        <option value='3'>three</option>                                                                                                                  
    </select>                                                                                                                                             
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [querystring encoding of a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up going with a RegExp match to override the options.
jQuery.param takes a hash and serialises it to a query_string 
but it doesn't provide the inverse (breaking up a query_string).

```
// put function into jQuery namespace
jQuery.redirect = function(url, params) {

    url = url || window.location.href || '';
    url =  url.match(/\?/) ? url : url + '?';

    for ( var key in params ) {
        var re = RegExp( ';?' + key + '=?[^&;]*', 'g' );
        url = url.replace( re, '');
        url += ';' + key + '=' + params[key]; 
    }  
    // cleanup url 
    url = url.replace(/[;&]$/, '');
    url = url.replace(/\?[;&]/, '?'); 
    url = url.replace(/[;&]{2}/g, ';');
    // $(location).attr('href', url);
    window.location.replace( url ); 
};
```

Then in the html

```
$('#selector').change(function(){ 
   $.redirect( location.href, { id : $(this).val() })
})
```

Thanks to everyone that responded.

Answer (score 7):

setting `window.location.search` will update the url's query string (and overwrite a value if it already exits)

```
$('#selector').change(function(){  
  window.location.search = "id=" + $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: What browser? Whats your HTML and JS look like?

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaking `.search` for a 'search' querystring parameter. Really `search` means the entire querystring in the DOM's location object.

Answer (score 7):

Based on CoffeeMonster's answer:

There is a problem when the location.href contains a hash part:
`www.example.com#hash` becomes `www.example.com#hash?id=whatever` which results in `?id=whatever` not being interpreted by the server.

Fixed it by removing the hash part of the url: `url.split("#")[0];`

```
// put function into jQuery namespace
jQuery.redirect = function(url, params) {

    url = url || window.location.href || '';
    url = url.split("#")[0];
    url =  url.match(/\?/) ? url : url + '?';

    for ( var key in params ) {
        var re = RegExp( ';?' + key + '=?[^&;]*', 'g' );
        url = url.replace( re, '');
        url += ';' + key + '=' + params[key]; 
    }  
    // cleanup url 
    url = url.replace(/[;&]$/, '');
    url = url.replace(/\?[;&]/, '?'); 
    url = url.replace(/[;&]{2}/g, ';');
    // $(location).attr('href', url);
    window.location.replace( url ); 
};
```

Now `www.example.com#hash` becomes `www.example.com?id=whatever`

Comment: Now, for bonus points, re-attach the hash to the end of the url. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This works like a charm:

```
jQuery.redirect = function( url ) {
   window.location.replace( url );  
};
$( "#selector" ).change( function() {
    var href = window.location.href.substring( 0, window.location.href.indexOf( '?' ) );
    $.redirect( href + '?id=' + $( this ).val() );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the split function:

```
var url = location.href.split('?')[0] + '?;id=' + $(this).val();
```

`split` returns a list made up of the string split up by the string (like '?'), with that string removed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the alleged solution is not working with specific variable names. Especially the line:

```
RegExp( ';?' + key + '=?[^&;]*', 'g' )
```

If key is a character sequence present elsewhere within the querystring, that occurrence will be mistakenly replaced also (try one letter, e.g. 'a'). This is because the regex leaves the string boundaries open (leading ';' and trailing '=' are both optional). Maybe the epxression better be something like:

```
RegExp( '[;&]' + key + '=?[^&;]*', 'g' )
```

Though I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Nice bug find!
Just checked my code and I'm passing in `client_id=12;project_id=45; ` etc. but I see how easily it would break with just `id=`
I think I'll go with something like 
    `RegExp( '[;&]?\b' ... )`
Will test when I get to work. Thanks.