# Toggle query string variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I've been banging my head over this.

Using jquery or javascript, how can I toggle variables & values and then rebuild the query string? For example, my starting URL is:

```
http://example.com?color=red&size=small,medium,large&shape=round
```

Then, if the user clicks a button labeled "red", I want to end up with:

```
http://example.com?size=small,medium,large&shape=round //color is removed
```

Then, if the user clicks "red" again, I want to end up with:

```
http://example.com?size=small,medium,large&shape=round&color=red //color is added back
```

Then, if the user clicks a button labeled "medium", I want to end up with:

```
http://example.com?size=small,large&shape=round&color=red //medium is removed from list
```

Then, if the user clicks the labeled "medium" again, I want to end up with:

```
http://example.com?size=small,large,medium&shape=round&color=red //medium added back
```

It doesn't really matter what order the variable are in; I've just been tacking them to the end.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053157/how-to-use-jquery-to-manipulate-the-querystring/2054100#2054100

Comment: Doesn't really handle multiple values in a single variable, but I can probably piece it together. Thanks for the find.

Comment: Sorry I did not have time to make a generic thing for you

Comment: this is very interested question, thank you!

Comment: Gotta say people... every one of these solutions rocked!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function toggle(url, key, val) {
    var out = [],
        upd = '',
        rm = "([&?])" + key + "=([^&]*?,)?" + val + "(,.*?)?(&.*?)?$",
        ad = key + "=",
        rmrplr = function(url, p1, p2, p3, p4) {
            if (p2) {
                if (p3) out.push(p1, key, '=', p2, p3.substr(1));
                else out.push(p1, key, '=', p2.substr(0, p2.length - 1));
            } else {
                if (p3) out.push(p1, key, '=', p3.substr(1));
                else out.push(p1);
            }
            if (p4) out.push(p4);
            return out.join('').replace(/([&?])&/, '$1').replace(/[&?]$/, ''); //<!2
        },
        adrplr = function(s) {
            return s + val + ',';
        };
    if ((upd = url.replace(new RegExp(rm), rmrplr)) != url) return upd;
    if ((upd = url.replace(new RegExp(ad), adrplr)) != url) return upd;
    return url + (/\?.+/.test(url) ? '&' : '?') + key + '=' + val; //<!1
}
```

params self described enough, hope this help.

!1: changed from `...? '&' : ''` to `... ? '&' : '?'`

!2: changed from `.replace('?&','?')...` to `.replace(/([&?]&)/,'$1')...`

http://jsfiddle.net/ycw7788/Abxj8/

Comment: This is really cool and very compact. But I think I'm hitting a bug. When sending key/value pair "color=red" into toggle(), then sending the same key/value pair back into toggle() again, then sending the same key/value pair in for the third time, I lose the "?".

Comment: One final bug here. Toggle on three different values from three different keys. Then, toggle off the second value. You end up with "&&" in the query string.

Comment: You should properly escape `key` and `val` prior using it. For example, when you use `key=(foo`, your code will throw an error, since `(` has a special RegExp meaning.

Answer (score 6):

I have written a function, which efficiently results in the expected behaviour, without use of any libraries or frameworks. A **dynamic** demo can be found at **this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w8D2G/1/**

### Documentation

**Definitions**:
*The shown example values will be used at the Usage section, below*
  -   Haystack - The string to search in (default = query string. e.g: `?size=small,medium`)
  -   Needle - The key to search for. Example: `size`
  -   Value - The value to replace/add. Example: `medium`.

**Usage** (Example: `input > output`):

1. `qs_replace(needle, value)`
   If value exists, remove: `?size=small,medium > ?size=small`
   If value not exists, add: `?size=small > size=small,medium`
2. `qs_replace(needle, options)`     Object options. Recognised options:

   - **`find`**
     String. Returns `true` if the value exists, `false` otherwise.
   - **`add`**, **`remove`** or **`toggle`**
     String. Add/remove the given value to/from `needle`. If `remove` is used, and the value was the only value, `needle` is also removed. A value won't be added if it already exists.
   - **`ignorecase`**
     Ignore case while looking for the search terms (`needle`, `add`, `remove` or `find`).
   - **`separator`**
     Specify a separator to separate values of `needle`. Default to comma (`,`).

**Note** :   A different value for String `haystack` can also be defined, by adding it as a first argument: `qs_replace(haystack, needle, value)` or `qs_replace(haystack, needle, options)`

Code (examples at bottom). **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w8D2G/1/**:

```
function qs_replace(haystack, needle, options) {
    if(!haystack || !needle) return ""; // Without a haystack or needle.. Bye
    else if(typeof needle == "object") {
        options = needle;
        needle = haystack;
        haystack = location.search;
    } else if(typeof options == "undefined") {
        options = needle;
        needle = haystack;
        haystack = location.search;
    }

    if(typeof options == "string" && options != "") {
        options = {remove: options};
        var toggle = true;
    } else if(typeof options != "object" || options === null) {
        return haystack;
    } else {
        var toggle = !!options.toggle;
        if (toggle) {
            options.remove = options.toggle;
            options.toggle = void 0;
        }
    }

    var find = options.find,
        add = options.add,
        remove = options.remove || options.del, //declare remove
        sep = options.sep || options.separator || ",", //Commas, by default

        flags = (options.ignorecase ? "i" :"");

    needle = encodeURIComponent(needle); //URL-encoding
    var pattern = regexp_special_chars(needle);
    pattern = "([?&])(" + pattern + ")(=|&|$)([^&]*)(&|$)";
    pattern = new RegExp(pattern, flags);
    var subquery_match = haystack.match(pattern);

    var before = /\?/.test(haystack) ? "&" : "?"; //Use ? if not existent, otherwise &
    var re_sep = regexp_special_chars(sep);

    if (!add || find) { //add is not defined, or find is used
        var original_remove = remove;
        if (subquery_match) {
            remove = encodeURIComponent(remove);
            remove = regexp_special_chars(remove);
            remove = "(^|" + re_sep + ")(" + remove + ")(" + re_sep + "|$)";
            remove = new RegExp(remove, flags);
            var fail = subquery_match[4].match(remove);
        } else {
            var fail = false;
        }
        if (!add && !fail && toggle) add = original_remove;
    }
    if(find) return !!subquery_match || fail;
    if (add) { //add is a string, defined previously
        add = encodeURIComponent(add);
        if(subquery_match) {
            var re_add = regexp_special_chars(add);
            re_add = "(^|" + re_sep + ")(" + re_add + ")(?=" + re_sep + "|$)";
            re_add = new RegExp(re_add, flags);
            if (subquery_match && re_add.test(subquery_match[4])) {
                return haystack;
            }
            if (subquery_match[3] != "=") {
                subquery_match = "$1$2=" + add + "$4$5";
            } else {
                subquery_match = "$1$2=$4" + sep + add + "$5";
            }
            return haystack.replace(pattern, subquery_match);
        } else {
            return haystack + before + needle + "=" + add;
        }
    } else if(subquery_match){ // Remove part. We can only remove if a needle exist
        if(subquery_match[3] != "="){
            return haystack;
        } else {
            return haystack.replace(pattern, function(match, prefix, key, separator, value, trailing_sep){
                // The whole match, example: &foo=bar,doo
                // will be replaced by the return value of this function
                var newValue = value.replace(remove, function(m, pre, bye, post){
                    return pre == sep && post == sep ? sep : pre == "?" ? "?" : "";
                });
                if(newValue) { //If the value has any content
                    return prefix + key + separator + newValue + trailing_sep;
                } else {
                    return prefix == "?" ? "?" : trailing_sep; //No value, also remove needle
                }
            }); //End of haystack.replace
        } //End of else if
    } else {
        return haystack;
    }

    // Convert string to RegExp-safe string
    function regexp_special_chars(s){
        return s.replace(/([[^$.|?*+(){}\\])/g, '\\$1');
    }
}
```

Examples (**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w8D2G/1/**):

```
qs_replace('color', 'red'); //Toggle color=red
qs_replace('size', {add: 'medium'}); //Add `medium` if not exist to size
var starting_url = 'http://example.com?color=red&size=small,medium,large&shape=round'
starting_url = qs_replace(starting_url, 'color', 'red'); //Toggle red, thus remove
starting_url = qs_replace(starting_url, 'color', 'red'); //Toggle red, so add it
alert(starting_url);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution for your task: http://jsfiddle.net/mikhailov/QpjZ3/12/

```
var url = 'http://example.com?size=small,medium,large&shape=round';
var params = $.deparam.querystring(url);
var paramsResult = {};

var click1 = { size: 'small' };
var click2 = { size: 'xlarge' };
var click3 = { shape: 'round' };
var click4 = { shape: 'square' };

var clickNow = click4;

for (i in params) {
    var clickKey = _.keys(clickNow)[0];
    var clickVal = _.values(clickNow)[0];

    if (i == clickKey) {
       var ar = params[i].split(',');

       if (_.include(ar, clickVal)) {
           var newAr = _.difference(ar, [clickVal]);
       } else {
           var newAr = ar;
           newAr.push(clickVal);
       }
       paramsResult[i] = newAr.join(',');
    } else {
       paramsResult[i] = params[i];
    }

}

alert($.param(paramsResult)) // results see below
```

**Init params string**

```
{ size="small, medium,large", shape="round"} // size=small,medium,large&shape=round
```

**Results**

```
{ size="small"}   => { size="medium,large", shape="round"} //size=medium%2Clarge&shape=round

{ size="xlarge"}  => { size="small,medium,large,xlarge", shape="round"} // size=small%2Cmedium%2Clarge%2Cxlarge&shape=round

{ shape="round"}  => { size="small,medium,large", shape=""} //size=small%2Cmedium%2Clarge&shape=

{ shape="square"} => { size="small,medium,large", shape="round,square"} //size=small%2Cmedium%2Clarge&shape=round%2Csquare
```

Comment: @joeyr did you have a chance to try this out?

Comment: Yes - first test left a key with an empty value on the URL. Need to test more.

Comment: Can you copy-paste your input data and explain what doesn't work please?

Comment: @joeyr, this is a cleanest code you can find among answers and it works, you need to double check jsFiddle

Answer (score 2):

`productOptions` is the only thing you need to modify here to list all the available options and their default state. You only need to use the public API function `toggleOption()` to toggle an option.

```
(function(){
    //Just keep an object with all the options with flags if they are enabled or disabled:

    var productOptions = {

        color: {
            "red": true,
            "blue": true,
            "green": false
        },

        size: {
            "small": true,
            "medium": true,
            "large": true
        },

        shape: {
            "round": true
        }
    };


    //After this constructing query becomes pretty simple even without framework functions:

    function constructQuery(){
    var key, opts, qs = [], enc = encodeURIComponent, opt,
        optAr, i;

        for( key in productOptions ) {
        opts = productOptions[key];
        optAr = [];
            for( i in opts ) {
                if( opts[i] ) {
                optAr.push( i );
                }
            }

            if( !optAr.length ) {
            continue;
            }

        qs.push( enc( key ) + "=" + enc( optAr.join( "," ) ) );
        }

    return "?"+qs.join( "&" );
    };

    //To toggle a value and construct the new query, pass what you want to toggle to this function:

    function toggleOption( optionType, option ) {

        if( optionType in productOptions && option in productOptions[optionType] ) {
        productOptions[optionType][option] = !productOptions[optionType][option];
        }

    return constructQuery();
    }

window.toggleOption = toggleOption;
})()
```

Example use:

```
// "%2C" = url encoded version of ","

toggleOption(); //Default query returned:
"?color=red%2Cblue&size=small%2Cmedium%2Clarge&shape=round"

toggleOption( "color", "red" ); //Red color removed:
"?color=blue&size=small%2Cmedium%2Clarge&shape=round"

toggleOption( "color", "blue" ); //Blue color removed, no color options so color doesn't show up at all:
"?size=small%2Cmedium%2Clarge&shape=round"

toggleOption( "color", "blue" ); //Blue color enabled again:
"?color=blue&size=small%2Cmedium%2Clarge&shape=round"

toggleOption( "shape", "round" ); //The only shape option removed
"?color=blue&size=small%2Cmedium%2Clarge"
```

Comment: This is awesome answer! Can you provide jfFiddle please? It it works, you will win a bounty, here is end of it in 20hours

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hSp4J/. It has the urldecoded version in the html and raw results in console log

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and this may give the desire result

```
<script>
var url='http://example.com?color=red&size=small,medium,large&shape=round';
var mySplitResult = url.split("?");
var domain=mySplitResult[0];
var qstring=mySplitResult[1];
var proparr=new Array();
var valarr=new Array();
var mySplitArr = qstring.split("&");
for (i=0;i<mySplitArr.length;i++){ 
    var temp = mySplitArr[i].split("=");
    proparr[i]=temp[0];
    valarr[i]=temp[1].split(",");   
 }
function toggle(property,value)
{
    var index;
    var yes=0;
    for (i=0;i<proparr.length;i++){ 
    if(proparr[i]==property)
    index=i;
    }
    if(index==undefined){
    proparr[i]=property;
    index=i;
    valarr[index]=new Array();  
    }   
    for (i=0;i<valarr[index].length;i++){ 
        if(valarr[index][i]==value){
        valarr[index].splice(i,1);
        yes=1;
        }   
    }
    if(!yes)
    {
    valarr[index][i]=value;
    }
    var furl=domain +'?';
    var test=new Array();
    for(i=0;i<proparr.length;i++)
    {
    if(valarr[i].length)
    {
    test[i]=valarr[i].join(",");
    furl +=proparr[i]+"="+test[i]+"&";  
    }   
    }
    furl=furl.substr(0,furl.length-1)
    alert(furl);
}
</script>


<div>
<input id="color" type="button" value="Toggle Red" onclick="toggle('color','red')"/>
<input id="shape" type="button" value="Toggle shape" onclick="toggle('shape','round')"/>
<input id="size" type="button" value="Toggle Small" onclick="toggle('size','small')"/>
<input id="size" type="button" value="Toggle large" onclick="toggle('size','large')"/>
<input id="size" type="button" value="Toggle medium" onclick="toggle('size','medium')"/>
<input id="size" type="button" value="Toggle new" onclick="toggle('new','yes')"/>
</div>
```