# Serialize object to query string in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, query-string

I'm trying to find information on how to serialize an object to query string format, but all my searches are drowning in results on how to go the other way (string/form/whatever to JSON).

I have

```
{ one: 'first', two: 'second' }
```

and I want

```
?one=first&two=second
```

Is there a good way to do this? I don't mind plugins or whatnots - if the code I find is not a plugin, I'll probably re-write it to one anyway...

Comment: Here are some nice plain JS solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object Some of them are not longer than the framwork solutions here.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

You want `$.param()`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Specifically, you want this:

```
var data = { one: 'first', two: 'second' };
var result = $.param(data);
```

When given something like this:

```
{a: 1, b : 23, c : "te!@#st"}
```

`$.param` will return this:

```
a=1&b=23&c=te!%40%23st
```

Comment: Note that if you have an array in your object it doesn't get parameterized correctly.

Comment: @crv: Right. JSON is probably best in that case

Comment: @crv I have an array in mine and it is working fine.

Comment: This won't work with asp.net 4.0 because of the `&` in the query string without you specifically setting your `requestValidationMode="2.0"`

Comment: It doesn't handle nested objects correctly.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 79):

For a quick non-JQuery function...

```
function jsonToQueryString(json) {
    return '?' + 
        Object.keys(json).map(function(key) {
            return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' +
                encodeURIComponent(json[key]);
        }).join('&');
}
```

Note this doesn't handle arrays or nested objects.

Comment: Cool, works! I've only added `if ( json[key] != null )` for omitting nulls

Comment: This is a nice, JavaScript-only solution. One can assign the call to `Object.keys` to a `params` variable and `return params.length && params.join('&') || ""` for cases where the object might be empty, i.e., `json={}`.

Comment: This works better than `$.param` because param encodes for forms not urls, so with param space becomes `+` instead of `%20` which can cause all kinds of issues, especially with MVC

Comment: Using ES6 it's a pretty clean and neat solution for simple JavaScript objects https://gist.github.com/magician11/c16ae65cacd5cdb793f5f8215c1ef811

Comment: `jsonToQueryString({ query: true, options: { nested: true }})` is return object[Object] :( `?query=true&options=%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

Answer (score 15):

Another option might be [node-querystring](https://github.com/hapijs/qs).

It's available in both `npm` and `bower`, which is why I have been using it.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively YUI has http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/QueryString.html#method_stringify.

For example:

```
var data = { one: 'first', two: 'second' };
var result = Y.QueryString.stringify(data);
```

Comment: It is not maintained any more.