# Flatten a javascript object to pass as querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, flatten

I have a javascript object that I need to flatten into a string so that I can pass as querystring, how would I do that? i.e:

`{ cost: 12345, insertBy: 'testUser' }` would become `cost=12345&insertBy=testUser`

I can't use jQuery AJAX call for this call, I know we can use that and pass the object in as `data` but not in this case. Using jQuery to flatten to object would be okay though.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialize JSON to query string in JavaScript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308846/serialize-json-to-query-string-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Please search before posting. This has been asked and answered before.

Comment: Sorry, I kept searching for "flatten" as the keyword and couldn't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You want [`jQuery.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param):

```
var str = $.param({ cost: 12345, insertBy: 'testUser' });
// "cost=12345&insertBy=testUser"
```

Note that this is the function used internally by jQuery to serialize objects passed as the `data` argument.

Answer (score 84):

Here's a non-jQuery version:

```
function toQueryString(obj) {
    var parts = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            parts.push(encodeURIComponent(i) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[i]));
        }
    }
    return parts.join("&");
}
```

Comment: When I try this it uses the parameter number, not the name for the first part of the query? Javascript drives me nuts.

Comment: @ElectricLlama: Are you using an array? Do you have some example code?

Comment: My mistake, I mixed up the parameters being passed into the function and it performed the operation on a string rather then a object.

Comment: Should you actually call encodeURIComponent on the key?

Comment: @RussSavage: Yes. The whole thing needs to be URL-encoded.

Comment: this seems to only work for shallow objects. with deep-nested objects you get =object

Comment: @codeMonkey: Yes, that's intentional. It's a simple example. If you want to pass an object in a query string then you'll need some way of serializing that object, which is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Why are you checking `i` existance in `obj` when you are iterating through the properties with `for in` loop?

Comment: @razzak: Because `obj` could have inherited properties from its prototype that we don't want to include in the query string we're generating. Example: http://jsbin.com/botapabomo/edit?html,js

Answer (score 39):

My ES6 version (pure Javascript, no jQuery):

```
function toQueryString(paramsObject) {
  return Object
    .keys(paramsObject)
    .map(key => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(paramsObject[key])}`)
    .join('&')
  ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet!

Comment: Great! But I added `.filter(key => paramsObject[key] !== null)` (or something else) before calling `.map(...)` to prevent including null values

Comment: @Daria you can actually just omit the test and `.filter` will automatically strip null values iirc

Comment: @robertmain you wouldn't want to do that if you cared about values like 0 or false. [0, 1, 2, false, null, undefined].filter(x => x) // Array [ 1, 2 ]

Answer (score 19):

This is an old question, but at the top of Google searches, so I'm adding this for completeness.

If 1) you don't want to user jQuery, but 2) you want to covert a *nested* object to a query string, then (building off of Tim Down and Guy's answers), use this:

```
function toQueryString(obj, urlEncode) {
    //
    // Helper function that flattens an object, retaining key structer as a path array:
    //
    // Input: { prop1: 'x', prop2: { y: 1, z: 2 } }
    // Example output: [
    //     { path: [ 'prop1' ],      val: 'x' },
    //     { path: [ 'prop2', 'y' ], val: '1' },
    //     { path: [ 'prop2', 'z' ], val: '2' }
    // ]
    //
    function flattenObj(x, path) {
        var result = [];

        path = path || [];
        Object.keys(x).forEach(function (key) {
            if (!x.hasOwnProperty(key)) return;

            var newPath = path.slice();
            newPath.push(key);

            var vals = [];
            if (typeof x[key] == 'object') {
                vals = flattenObj(x[key], newPath);
            } else {
                vals.push({ path: newPath, val: x[key] });
            }
            vals.forEach(function (obj) {
                return result.push(obj);
            });
        });

        return result;
    } // flattenObj

    // start with  flattening `obj`
    var parts = flattenObj(obj); // [ { path: [ ...parts ], val: ... }, ... ]

    // convert to array notation:
    parts = parts.map(function (varInfo) {
        if (varInfo.path.length == 1) varInfo.path = varInfo.path[0];else {
            var first = varInfo.path[0];
            var rest = varInfo.path.slice(1);
            varInfo.path = first + '[' + rest.join('][') + ']';
        }
        return varInfo;
    }); // parts.map

    // join the parts to a query-string url-component
    var queryString = parts.map(function (varInfo) {
        return varInfo.path + '=' + varInfo.val;
    }).join('&');
    if (urlEncode) return encodeURIComponent(queryString);else return queryString;
}
```

Use like:

```
console.log(toQueryString({
    prop1: 'x',
    prop2: {
        y: 1,
        z: 2
    }
}, false));
```

Which outputs:

```
prop1=x&prop2[y]=1&prop2[z]=2
```

Answer (score 18):

Here is another non-jQuery version that utilizes lodash or underscore if you're already using one of those libraries:

```
var toQueryString = function(obj) {
  return _.map(obj,function(v,k){
    return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(v);
  }).join('&');
};
```

^ I wrote that 5 years ago. An updated and more succinct version of this would now (Oct 2019) be:

```
var input = { cost: 12345, insertBy: 'testUser' };
Object.entries(input)
  .map(([k,v]) => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(v)}`)
  .join('&');
// cost=12345&insertBy=testUser
```

Check that the runtime that you're targeting supports Object.entries() or that you're using a transpiler like Babel or TypeScript if it doesn't.

Answer (score 16):

Try the [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) method:

```
var result = $.param({ cost: 12345, insertBy: 'testUser' });
```

Answer (score 4):

General JavaScript:

```
function toParam(obj) {
  var str = "";
  var seperator = "";
  for (key in obj) {
    str += seperator;
    str += enncodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]);
    seperator = "&";
  }
  return str;
}


toParam({ cost: 12345, insertBy: 'testUser' })
"cost=12345&insertBy=testUser"
```

Answer (score 4):

Another version:

```
function toQueryString(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(k => {
      return encodeURIComponent(k) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[k])
    })
    .join("&");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var myObj = { cost: 12345, insertBy: 'testUser' },
    param = '',
    url   = 'http://mysite.com/mypage.php';    

for (var p in myObj) {
  if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
    param += encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(myObj[p]) + "&";
  }
}

window.location.href = url + "?" + param;
```

Comment: There is an bug on this answer, it will leave the final `param` with a trailing `&`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
function serialize(obj)
{
    let str = []

    for(var p in obj)
    {
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]))
    }

    return str.join('&')
}
```

try on JSFiddle on this link https://jsfiddle.net/yussan/kwmnkca6/

Answer (score 1):

ES6 version of [Jrop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31415775/740566) (also parses nested params)

```
const toQueryString = (obj, urlEncode = false) => {
  if (!obj) return null;
  const flattenObj = (x, path = []) => {
    const result = [];
    Object.keys(x).forEach((key) => {
      if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, key)) return;
      const newPath = path.slice();
      newPath.push(key);
      let vals = [];
      if (typeof x[key] === 'object') {
        vals = flattenObj(x[key], newPath);
      } else {
        vals.push({ path: newPath, val: x[key] });
      }
      vals.forEach((v) => {
        return result.push(v);
      });
    });
    return result;
  };

  let parts = flattenObj(obj);
  parts = parts.map((varInfo) => {
    if (varInfo.path.length === 1) {
      varInfo.path = varInfo.path[0]; // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
    } else {
      const first = varInfo.path[0];
      const rest = varInfo.path.slice(1);
      varInfo.path = `${first}[${rest.join('][')}]`; // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
    }
    return varInfo;
  });

  const queryString = parts.map((varInfo) => {
    return `${varInfo.path}=${varInfo.val}`;
  }).join('&');
  if (urlEncode) {
    return encodeURIComponent(queryString);
  }
  return queryString;
};
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) library it can be done as:

```js
let data = {}

_.map(data, (value, key) => `${key}=${value}`)
.join("&");
```

> Note that this library has been imported as:

```js
window._ = require('lodash');
```