# Accessing Post Data via JSTL - Angular $post

Tags: jsp, post, parameters, jstl

How can I print the `Request Payload` data to the page via JSTL?

[image: Post Data]

In the image above I am sending a post to a `jstl` controller.  Now I can access the query string parameters easily e.g. `${param.test}` will print out the test parameter.

But I am not sure how to access the data in the Request Payload I have tried the ${requestScope} object `${requestScope.PAY}` but the data does not seem to be there.

Is there an accessible object that holds this data?  If not what is the best work around?

**Update**

I don't know how relevant, but I am using angular's `$http.post` for the call.

Comment: try same way `${param.PAY}`

Comment: @JigarJoshi unfortunately that does not work for me either..  Do you know why that might be the case?

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525982/getting-request-payload-from-post-request-in-java-servlet), I think OP there was in the same case as you.  There's also a solution (before using the elaborated example, please read the comments belwo wrt encoding issues), however you'll have to code that solution in a servlet as adding Java code to JSP's should be avoided.

Comment: To clarify previous comment a bit: what you see here as "Request Payload" is actually the body of the request, so you need a method to extract the body from the request.  It's not accessible via the headers or parameters.

Comment: @fvu is this something that could be addressed by the way the post is being initiated?  I was looking at a comment from the link you gave: `It'd be interesting to see the JavaScript code sending the request. It's apparently composing the request parameters in a wrong way. –  BalusC` If possible I would want to correct the issue on the post side before going to a `servlet` solution.  I appreciate the info

Comment: `This seems relevant as well` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190166/angularjs-any-way-for-http-post-to-send-request-parameters-instead-of-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to transform your post request in Angular to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So in your application you'll do something like this.

```
var app = angular.module('myAapp', [])
    app.config(function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider
        .defaults
        .headers
        .post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';

    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function (data) {
        return angular.isObject(data) && String(data) !== '[object File]' ? jQuery.param(data) : data;
    }];
    })
```

This should work.

Comment: You are using the jQuery.param function, for those looking for a javascript alternative. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5505137/1022305

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1) When you send the request, send it as content-type equal to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of "text/json", and then you can access the parameters with ${param.PAY} just as if it was a query string parameter.  The "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is the default encoding when you POST an HTML form.

-or if that's not an option because you don't control the request side-

2) You will need to use a servlet or JSP scriptlet to access the contents, as in this question:  [HttpServletRequest get JSON POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831680/httpservletrequest-get-post-data)

Comment: Thanks for the info, unfortunately just changing the `content-type` did not work for me I also had to perform a transformation on the data using `jQuery's $.param()` function as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190166/angularjs-any-way-for-http-post-to-send-request-parameters-instead-of-json