# Convert javascript object into a url query

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648892/convert-url-parameters-to-a-javascript-object), namely, convert a JavaScript object into the query at the end of a url. This is for a potentially huge, and completely randomized string in terms of keys/values. For example,

```
activity = {myKey:"randomString"}

'<img src="images/image.gif?' + activity + '">'
```

Would give me back:

```
<img src='images/image.gif?{myKey:"randomString"}'>
```

Comment: duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/q/5505085/798682](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5505085/798682)? i see your example is different, but your "opposite this question" matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
var queryValues={
  param:"0",
  s:"stack",
  o:"overflow",
  myKey:"randomString"
};
var qparts=Object.keys(queryValues).map(function(k){
  return [k,queryValues[k]].map(encodeURIComponent).join("=");
});
var queryString=qparts.length?"?"+qparts.join("&"):"";


/*
queryString:
?param=0&s=stack&o=overflow&myKey=randomString
*/
```

Then modify the original url by concatenating with the queryString.  Like so:

```
images/image.gif?param=0&s=stack&o=overflow&myKey=randomString
```

---

Also, from your question, you wanted a url that looks like this:

```
images/image.gif?{myKey:"randomString"}
```

Which appears malformed and not quite the opposite of what was posted in the other question you linked to.  So I gave you a snippet to produce a well-formed query string instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myURL = '<img src="images/image.gif?' + JSON.stringify(activity) + '">';
```

Comment: You'll actually want to do `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(activity))`.

Comment: What he said, in terms of encoding but in particular what problem are you trying to solve?