# How to access a javascript object from .js file in C# code behind file .aspx.cs file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How to access a javascript object from `.js` file in C# code behind file `.aspx.cs` file?

```
var user={name:"john";age:"12"};
```

I want to access this user object in C# code behind file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java ... Are you sure you mean "Java object"?

Comment: Just for stater you can refer this link [Webmethod using Jquery Ajax](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) and try impleting the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are may ways one is you can pass it in query string. Here is a [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505085/flatten-a-javascript-object-to-pass-as-querystring)

Use like

```
str = $.param({name:"john";age:"12"});
```

and use this str in parameter.

Save individual value to hidden field and then get it in code behind.