# Setting query string using Fetch GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, fetch-api

I'm trying to use the new [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

I am making a `GET` request like this:

```
var request = new Request({
  url: 'http://myapi.com/orders',
  method: 'GET'
});
fetch(request);
```

However, I'm unsure how to add a query string to the `GET` request. Ideally, I want to be able to make a `GET` request to a `URL` like:

```
'http://myapi.com/orders?order_id=1'
```

In `jQuery` I could do this by passing `{order_id: 1}` as the `data` parameter of `$.ajax()`. Is there an equivalent way to do that with the new `Fetch API`?

Answer (score 762, accepted):

A concise, modern approach:

```
fetch('https://example.com?' + new URLSearchParams({
    foo: 'value',
    bar: 2,
}))
```

**How it works:** When a string (e.g. the URL) is being concatenated with an instance of [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams), [its toString() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/toString) will automatically be called to convert the instance into a string representation, which happens to be a properly encoded query string. If the automatic invoking of `toString()` is too magical for your liking, you may prefer to explicitly call it like so: `fetch('https://...' + new URLSearchParams(...).toString())`

A complete example of a fetch request with query parameters:

```js
// Real example you can copy-paste and play with.
// jsonplaceholder.typicode.com provides a dummy rest-api
// for this sort of purpose.
async function doAsyncTask() {
  const url = (
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?' +
    new URLSearchParams({ postId: 1 }).toString()
  );

  const result = await fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json());

  console.log('Fetched from: ' + url);
  console.log(result);
}

doAsyncTask();
```

---

If you are using/supporting...

- **IE:** Internet Explorer does not provide native support for URLSearchParams or fetch, but there are [polyfills](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill) [available](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-ie8).
- **Node:** As of Node 18 there is native support for the fetch API (in version 17.5 it was behind the `--experimental-fetch` flag). In older versions, you can add the fetch API through a package like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch). URLSearchParams comes with Node, and can be found as a global object since version 10. In older version you can find it at `require('url').URLSearchParams`.
- **TypeScript:** The values provided to `URLSearchParams` will be auto-coerced into a string, which is why TypeScript's definition for `URLSearchParams` requires you to provide all values as strings. Those who don't use TypeScript may be comfortable providing other value types to this function if they feel the coercion behavior is intuitive. For examples, numbers will behave exactly as you would expect, while the way arrays get implicitly coerced may cause confusion to future readers.
- **TypeScript v4 or older with Node:** Older versions of TypeScript did not offer type definitions for the global URLSearchParams in the Node environment. The simplest workaround is to just import it from the `url` module. This later got resolved at some point during v4 (I'm not sure what the exact version is that fixes this). See [this issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/34960) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I think this should be accepted answer. The asked to pass parameters to the fetch API, and although that isn't possible, this answer is pretty bloody close to what that would look like in structure.

Comment: This doesn't appear to correctly handle multiple values for the same key. I was expecting to be able to write `new URLSearchParams({foo: ['bar', 'baz']})` but rather than `foo=bar&foo=baz` it gets escaped as `foo=bar%Cbaz`

Comment: @jymbob to have multiple values, you'll have to use the .append() method on URLSearchParams. e.g. `s = new URLSearchParams({foo: 'bar'}); s.append('foo', 'baz'); s.toString()`. Alternativly, the constructor can take a list of lists instead of an object. `new URLSearchParams([['foo', 'bar'], ['foo', 'baz']]).toString()` See the docs page for more usage info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: @ScottyJamison thanks for responding. I had discovered that from the docs, but it sort of renders URLSearchParams useless for me if I can't pass in a dict and get the expected search param out at the other end.

Comment: An even more concise approach would be to use string interpolation:
```
`https://example.com?${new URLSearchParams({foo: 'value'})}`
```   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: For anyone wondering why URLSearchParams does not work with arrays, it's because there's no standard way to represent array data as search params, and you'll find competing ways to do this task. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string

Comment: Node supports fetch now!

Comment: Be aware that when using typescript you have to use strings as values only. So `bar: 2` should be `bar: '2'`.

Comment: If you're already using URLSearchParams, then it might be worth just building the whole URL with the URL constructor. Not a single liner but it'll be cleaner if you do `const url = new URL(path, baseURL);` , `url.search = new URLSearchParams(query);`, `fetch(url.href, {});`. Then you can get a clean URL whether the query object is empty or not. That means that you won't get pointless trailing ? when there's no query parameter. Also, this is just personal opinion but I don't think object instantiation should occur in a string.

Answer (score 358):

**Update March 2017:**

[URL.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) support has officially landed in Chrome 51, but other browsers still require a [polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params).

---

The *official* way to work with query parameters is just to add them onto the URL. From [the spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-api), this is an example:

```
var url = new URL("https://geo.example.org/api"),
    params = {lat:35.696233, long:139.570431}
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))
fetch(url).then(/* … */)
```

However, I'm not sure Chrome supports the `searchParams` property of a URL (at the time of writing) so you might want to either use a [third party library](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) or [roll-your-own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505085/flatten-a-javascript-object-to-pass-as-querystring).

**Update April 2018:**

With the use of [URLSearchParams constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) you could assign a 2D array or a object and just assign that to the `url.search` instead of looping over all keys and append them

```
var url = new URL('https://sl.se')

var params = {lat:35.696233, long:139.570431} // or:
var params = [['lat', '35.696233'], ['long', '139.570431']]

url.search = new URLSearchParams(params).toString();

fetch(url)
```

Sidenote: `URLSearchParams` is also available in NodeJS

```
const { URL, URLSearchParams } = require('url');
```

Comment: There's also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/toString, tho as of this writing it's still making its way through spec, and not well-supported yet. And the API is more like Java than JS. :/

Comment: See http://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams for support for the `URLSearchParams` interface; I would *assume* (though I'm not 100% certain) that the browsers in red there are exactly the browsers for which `URL` objects will not have the `.searchParams` property. Importantly, Edge still does not have support.

Comment: From the documentation: "Note that using a URLSearchParams instance is deprecated; soon browsers will just use a USVString for the init."   source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams

Comment: @pakman I don't think those docs are up to date. The `init` [can be an object containing key/value pairs](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlsearchparams) (as shown here). Perhaps the MDN docs are referring to passing in an instance of `URLSearchParams` as the parameter to an existing `URLSearchParams`

Comment: `new URLSearchParams` doesn't seem to work correctly with `Array` properties. I expected it to convert the property `array: [1, 2]` to `array[]=1&array[]=2`, but converted it to `array=1,2`.   
Manually using the `append` method of it does result in `array=1&array=2`, but I would have to iterate over params object, and do that only for array types, not very ergonomic.

Comment: @erandros The MDN docs do say that only USVString is a valid type to pass to URLSearchParms as constructor argument and since that seems to be a valid query string it is no use to try and pass anything to the constructor to get a valid query string. You can try the following: `var pr = new URLSearchParams();
[['a',1],['a',2]].forEach(
  ([key,val])=>pr.append(key,val)
);
pr.toString()`

Comment: @HMR Not sure where you are seeing that, but MDN docs state that `init` can be: "A USVString instance, a URLSearchParams instance, a sequence of USVStrings, or a record containing USVStrings"

Comment: @CodingIntrigue I read `soon browsers will just use a USVString for the init. `, for now `new URLSearchParams([['a':1],['a':2]])` will work but for how long?

Comment: @HMR I queried this statement with the editor at MDN. I hope it is not correct!

Comment: It was indeed added in error :) https://github.com/mdn/sprints/issues/2856

Comment: `URL` is now a global in nodejs since v10.0.0: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html

Comment: `new URL('/relative/url')` throwing an error: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL

Comment: @SergeyNudnov The `URL` constructor accepts two arguments. The second one is to provide an absolute base URL for the relative URL provided in the first argument.

Answer (score 47):

```
let params = {
  "param1": "value1",
  "param2": "value2"
};

let query = Object.keys(params)
             .map(k => encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[k]))
             .join('&');

let url = 'https://example.com/search?' + query;

fetch(url)
  .then(data => data.text())
  .then((text) => {
    console.log('request succeeded with JSON response', text)
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('request failed', error)
  });
```

Comment: do you need to encode the key? i've never done that.

Comment: @chovy - you do if your key contains special characters, like "&". Most of the time it won't, but sometimes it can.

Comment: NOTE: encodeURIComponent can give bad results, e.g. it'll incorrectly encode a space as "%20" instead of "+" - this behavior is fine when you're percent encoding, for example, a URL's path (an intended use case), but query parameters are generally form-encoded, which follows an older version of the percent-encoding specification - you can use [URLSearchParams()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to properly encode/decode query parameters. See [this S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20) to learn more.

Comment: I rectract my previous comment. I've since learned that after the `?`, there's two allowed ways to encode a space, both `%20` and `+` are acceptable. So while both `URLSearchParams()` and `encodeURIComponent()` will give out different results, a server is supposed to be able to accept either.

Answer (score 33):

As already answered, this is per spec not possible with the `fetch`-API, yet. But I have to note:

If you are on `node`, there's the `querystring` package. It can stringify/parse objects/querystrings:

```
var querystring = require('querystring')
var data = { key: 'value' }
querystring.stringify(data) // => 'key=value'
```

...then just append it to the url to request.

---

However, the problem with the above is, that you always have to prepend a question mark (`?`). So, another way is to use the `parse` method from nodes `url` package and do it as follows:

```
var url = require('url')
var data = { key: 'value' }
url.format({ query: data }) // => '?key=value'
```

See `query` at https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_format_urlobj

This is possible, as it does internally just [this](https://github.com/isaacs/node-url/blob/355b861f83dbd7f54fdde91a21d5388900aa7f3d/url.js#L126-L132):

```
search = obj.search || (
    obj.query && ('?' + (
        typeof(obj.query) === 'object' ?
        querystring.stringify(obj.query) :
        String(obj.query)
    ))
) || ''
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `stringify` from [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string).

```js
import { stringify } from 'query-string';

fetch(`https://example.org?${stringify(params)}`)
```

Answer (score 10):

### encodeQueryString — encode an object as querystring parameters

```
/**
 * Encode an object as url query string parameters
 * - includes the leading "?" prefix
 * - example input — {key: "value", alpha: "beta"}
 * - example output — output "?key=value&alpha=beta"
 * - returns empty string when given an empty object
 */
function encodeQueryString(params) {
    const keys = Object.keys(params)
    return keys.length
        ? "?" + keys
            .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key)
                + "=" + encodeURIComponent(params[key]))
            .join("&")
        : ""
}

encodeQueryString({key: "value", alpha: "beta"})
 //> "?key=value&alpha=beta"
```

Answer (score 10):

You can set params on your `URL`'s `searchParams`:

```
const url = new URL('http://myapi.com/orders');
url.searchParams.set('order_id', '1');
fetch(url);
```

This has the advantage of building a request explicitly while allowing the original `URL` to be in any valid format.

Comment: I tested it in Firefox before making my comment and it didn’t work.

Comment: Here is a [live demo on JSBin](https://jsbin.com/gavirekawu/1/edit?js,console) in which I replace `fetch` with `console.log`. It logs the original URL from line one without the query string you attempt to add on line two when I test in Firefox, Safari, or Chrome.

Comment: For multiple query params 
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams({ one : '1' , two : '2' });
const url = new URL(`${process.env.API_URL}/messages?${searchParams.toString()}`);
fetch(url);

Answer (score 8):

I know this is stating the absolute obvious, but I feel it's worth adding this as an answer as it's the simplest of all:

```
const orderId = 1;
fetch('http://myapi.com/orders?order_id=' + orderId);
```

Comment: It's worth qualifying that this only works reliably with integer types.  If you use strings, especially user-supplied ones (like search criteria) then you have to escape the string, otherwise you can get odd results if characters like `/`, `+` or `&` appear in the string.

Comment: Using the Request object can help, especially if you want to use a function to build the request and then hand that to the fetch() call, but I don't think using it is "absolute obvious". Also, the url should not be specified in the object literal of config options; it should be passed separately as the 1st parameter to the Request constructor (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request).

Comment: @Gen1-1, ty. Made some edits. My sample was based on OP's snippet, but I simplified it a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this is better:

```
const withQuery = require('with-query');

fetch(withQuery('https://api.github.com/search/repositories', {
  q: 'query',
  sort: 'stars',
  order: 'asc',
}))
.then(res => res.json())
.then((json) => {
  console.info(json);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

## Solution without external packages

to perform a **GET** request using the fetch api I worked on this solution that doesn't require the installation of packages.

this is an example of a call to the google's map api

```
// encode to scape spaces
const esc = encodeURIComponent;
const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?';
const params = { 
    key: "asdkfñlaskdGE",
    address: "evergreen avenue",
    city: "New York"
};
// this line takes the params object and builds the query string
const query = Object.keys(params).map(k => `${esc(k)}=${esc(params[k])}`).join('&')
const res = await fetch(url+query);
const googleResponse = await res.json()
```

feel free to copy this code and paste it on the console to see how it works!!

the generated url is something like:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=asdkf%C3%B1laskdGE&address=evergreen%20avenue&city=New%20York
```

this is what I was looking before I decided to write this, enjoy :D

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I forgot to escape the query params.

Comment: Functionally identical to the [answer provided by Sudharshan three and a half years earlier](/a/42078312/4642212).

Comment: What’s the point of `const esc = encodeURIComponent` except making the code harder to read?

Answer (score 1):

Template literals are also a valid option here, and provide a few benefits.

You can include raw strings, numbers, boolean values, etc:

```
    let request = new Request(`https://example.com/?name=${'Patrick'}&number=${1}`);
```

You can include variables:

```
    let request = new Request(`https://example.com/?name=${nameParam}`);
```

You can include logic and functions:

```
    let request = new Request(`https://example.com/?name=${nameParam !== undefined ? nameParam : getDefaultName() }`);
```

As far as structuring the data of a larger query string, I like using an array concatenated to a string. I find it easier to understand than some of the other methods:

```
let queryString = [
  `param1=${getParam(1)}`,
  `param2=${getParam(2)}`,
  `param3=${getParam(3)}`,
].join('&');

let request = new Request(`https://example.com/?${queryString}`, {
  method: 'GET'
});
```

Comment: You have to be very careful with this method because it does not URL-escape the strings first.  So if you get a variable that contains a character like `+` or `&` then it won't work as expected and you'll end up with different parameters and values to what you thought.

Answer (score -1):

Was just working with Nativescript's fetchModule and figured out my own solution using string manipulation.
Append the query string bit by bit to the url. Here is an example where query is passed as a json object (query = {order_id: 1}):

```
function performGetHttpRequest(fetchLink='http://myapi.com/orders', query=null) {
    if(query) {
        fetchLink += '?';
        let count = 0;
        const queryLength = Object.keys(query).length;
        for(let key in query) {
            fetchLink += key+'='+query[key];
            fetchLink += (count < queryLength) ? '&' : '';
            count++;
        }
    }
    // link becomes: 'http://myapi.com/orders?order_id=1'
    // Then, use fetch as in MDN and simply pass this fetchLink as the url.
}
```

I tested this over a multiple number of query parameters and it worked like a charm :)
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is a good example of why you should use 3rd party libs - your code might be working fine, but someone already did it much better

Comment: This has the same drawbacks as [the answer by Evert](/a/43485348/4642212) and [the one by Pat Kearns](/a/46496234/4642212) already provided more than two years earlier. _“I tested this over a multiple number of query parameters and it worked like a charm”_ — You didn’t test this with anything relevant, then. [URLs](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax) have a syntax that can be tokenized on specific characters. Trying any of these characters in your function should make it obvious that this code is broken.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Two years later, I stand corrected. Thank you my friend.

Answer (score -1):

```
const query = {
    is_active: true,
};

let url = `${apiUrl}/<endPoint>`;

const searchParams = Object.keys(query).length ? new URLSearchParams(query).toString() : null;

if (searchParams) {url = `${url}?${searchParams}`}
```

for nextJs 13+

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: "GET",
  next: {
    // revalidate will be after 4 min
    revalidate: 240,
  },
  // cache: "no-cache",
});
```