# GET with query string with Fetch in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, query-string

I am making a request like this:

```
fetch("https://api.parse.com/1/users", {
  method: "GET",
  headers: headers,   
  body: body
})
```

How do I pass query string parameters? Do I simply add them to the URL? I couldn't find an example in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting query string using Fetch GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038857/setting-query-string-using-fetch-get-request)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Your first thought was right: just add them to the URL.

Remember you can use template strings (backticks) to simplify putting variables into the query.

```
const data = {foo:1, bar:2};

fetch(`https://api.parse.com/1/users?foo=${encodeURIComponent(data.foo)}&bar=${encodeURIComponent(data.bar)}`, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: headers,   
})
```

Answer (score 41):

#### Short answer

Just substitute values into the URL like this:

```
const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(someVariable);
fetch(`https://example.com/foo?bar=${encodedValue}`);
```

#### Longer answer

Yes, you just need to add the query string to the URL yourself. You should take care to escape your query string parameters, though - *don't* just construct a URL like

```
`https://example.com/foo?bar=${someVariable}`
```

unless you're confident that `someVariable` definitely doesn't contain any `&`, `=`, or other special characters.

If you were using `fetch` outside of React Native, you'd have the option of encoding query string parameters using [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). However, React Native [does not support `URLSearchParams`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9596). Instead, use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

For example:

```
const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(someVariable);
fetch(`https://example.com/foo?bar=${encodedValue}`);
```

If you want to serialise an object of keys and values into a query string, you could make a utility function to do that:

```
function objToQueryString(obj) {
  const keyValuePairs = [];
  for (const key in obj) {
    keyValuePairs.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
  }
  return keyValuePairs.join('&');
}
```

... and use it like this:

```
const queryString = objToQueryString({
    key1: 'somevalue',
    key2: someVariable,
});
fetch(`https://example.com/foo?${queryString}`);
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an es6 approach

```
const getQueryString = (queries) => {
    return Object.keys(queries).reduce((result, key) => {
        return [...result, `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(queries[key])}`]
    }, []).join('&');
};
```

Here we're taking in a queries object in the shape of `key: param`
We iterate and reduce through the keys of this object, building an array of encoded query strings.
Lastly we do a join and return this attachable query string.

Comment: Although we both know that the code is quite straight forward, still add some explanation is preferred for an answer.

Comment: example:
const data = {city:'Amman', country:'Jordan', month: 7, annual: false};
    
    fetch(`http://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCity?${getQueryString(data)}`, {
      method: "GET"
    })

Answer (score 4):

I did a small riff on [Mark Amery's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709587/mark-amery) answer that will pass Airbnb's eslint definitions since many teams seem to have that requirement these days.

```
function objToQueryString(obj) {
  const keyValuePairs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i += 1) {
    keyValuePairs.push(`${encodeURIComponent(Object.keys(obj)[i])}=${encodeURIComponent(Object.values(obj)[i])}`);
  }
  return keyValuePairs.join('&');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should, there are a few classes in JS, that can help you a handy one is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

e.g. if you had the params in a javascript object say

```
let params = {one: 'one', two: 'two'}
```

you could say this function

```
let queryString = new URLSearchParams()
for(let key in params){
  if(!params.hasOwnkey())continue
  queryString.append(key, params[key])
}
```

then you can get your nicely formatted query string by saying

```
queryString.toString()
```

Comment: -1; `URLSearchParams` doesn't exist in React Native. The only way to use it is via a polyfill, and this answer doesn't mention that.

Comment: I think this polyfill is included by default with React Native via [whatwg-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch) so `URLSearchParams` should be safe to use, at least as of React Native 0.59.

Answer (score 2):

My simple function to handle this:

```
/**
 * Get query string
 *
 * @param   {*}   query   query object (any object that Object.entries() can handle)
 * @returns {string}      query string
 */
function querystring(query = {}) {
  // get array of key value pairs ([[k1, v1], [k2, v2]])
  const qs = Object.entries(query)
    // filter pairs with undefined value
    .filter(pair => pair[1] !== undefined)
    // encode keys and values, remove the value if it is null, but leave the key
    .map(pair => pair.filter(i => i !== null).map(encodeURIComponent).join('='))
    .join('&');

  return qs && '?' + qs;
}

querystring({one: '#@$code', two: undefined, three: null, four: 100, 'fi##@ve': 'text'});
// "?one=%23%40%24code&three&four=100&fi%23%23%40ve=text"
querystring({});
// ""
querystring('one')
// "?0=o&1=n&2=e"
querystring(['one', 2, null, undefined]);
// "?0=one&1=2&2" (edited)
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works, but if you have more params than one it doesn't generalize. I suggest the following approach, which also handles array parameters:

```
let route = 'http://test.url.com/offices/search';
if (method == 'GET' && params) {
  const query = Object.keys(params)
    .map((k) => {
      if (Array.isArray(params[k])) {
        return params[k]
          .map((val) => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}[]=${encodeURIComponent(val)}`)
          .join('&');
      }

      return `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(params[k])}`;
    })
    .join('&');

  route += `?${query}`;
}
```