# How to pass parameter to an API get request in react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I wonder is there a way to pass a parameter from the client to the back-end API get Request. At this moment I hard coded the needed argument (name:"newName").

back-end route:

```
app.get('/api/get/beerWithComments', (req,res,next) =>{



    Beer.findOne({name:'newName'}) //I want to pass the correct name, now it's hard coded.
        .populate('comments').exec((err,beer) =>{
            if(err) return next(err);
            res.json(beer);
        });

});
```

My action method:

```
  export const fetchBeerWithComments =() => async dispatch => {
    const res= await axios.get('/api/get/beerWithComments');
    dispatch({type: FETCH_BEER_WITH_COMMENTS, payload : res.data });

}
```

I thought to pass the parameter here in. But I don't know if I can pass the argument to my back-end.

```
export const fetchBeerWithComments =(parameter) => async dispatch => {...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting query string using Fetch GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038857/setting-query-string-using-fetch-get-request)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the parameter `name` in the query string and read the parameter value in handler using `req.query` like

```
app.get('/api/get/beerWithComments', (req, res, next) =>{
  var qname = req.query.name || "";
  if(!qname.length) {
    res.status(404).json({"msg": 'Invalid name in query string'});
    res.end();
    return;
  }
  Beer.findOne({name: qname}) //I want to pass the correct name, now it's hard coded.
    .populate('comments').exec((err,beer) =>{
        if(err) return next(err);
        res.json(beer);
    });
});
```

And while calling GET API from the client side just add query string param `name` with respective value and it should work as you expected.
for eg URL will be like

```
export const fetchBeerWithComments =(parameter) => async dispatch => {
  const res= await axios.get('/api/get/beerWithComments?name=' + parameter);
  dispatch({type: FETCH_BEER_WITH_COMMENTS, payload : res.data });
}
```

Comment: Can u explain me this line of code : ` var qname = (req.query || {}).name || "";` ? thanks!

Comment: In js when an object is null/undefined/false or "", then referring to key inside that will throw an exception. By using short-circuit OR operator u can change such values to a known value. by using
 var qname = (req.query || {}).name || "";

In express, req.query will always be an object irrespective of client sends it or not. Hence we can modify our a code a bit. 
When a client doesn't send name param using .length on it will throw an exception so in that case code will shortcircuit it to a known value of empty string and length property will work and prevents runtime exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass it back you could just change the api endpoint to have a dynamic parameter e.g change the get endpoint to:

`/api/get/beerWithComments/:beerName`

So on the front end you can have

```
 export const fetchBeerWithComments = (beerName) => async dispatch => {
    const res= await axios.get(`/api/get/beerWithComments/${ beerName }`);
    dispatch({type: FETCH_BEER_WITH_COMMENTS, payload : res.data });
 }
```

And then on the backend

```
app.get('/api/get/beerWithComments/:beerName', (req,res,next) =>{
    Beer.findOne({name: req.params.beerName})
        .populate('comments').exec((err,beer) => {
            if(err) return next(err);
            res.json(beer);
     });
});
```