# Query string with fetch javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm working on a project and i want to define url object that will be passed to fetch ex. 
https://t1.testing.com/test/api/v1/blog?pagingindex=0&pagingresults=10

```js
const url_object = {
  url: `https://t1.testing.com/test/api/v1/blog`,
  url_params: {
    method: "POST",
    pagingindex: 0,
    pagingresults: 10
  }
};
```

and when i call `fetch(url_object.url, url_object.url_params)` i get an error. How can i incorporate this into fetch? So i need to allow user to define method and query string that will be passed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Have you tried just passing that same URL to `fetch` as the URL argument? BTW, [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) does not allow for properties in its initialization object other than those documented, and it takes two arguments: the URL, then the initialization object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting query string using Fetch GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038857/setting-query-string-using-fetch-get-request)

Answer (score 3):

You can have your cake and eat it too -- easily convert dictionary style objects to query parameters with no fuss:

```
var url = new URL('https://example.com/');
url.search = new URLSearchParams({blah: 'lalala', rawr: 'arwrar'}); 
console.log(url.toString()); // https://example.com/?blah=lalala&rawr=arwrar
```

Comment: This only works with absolute URLs. If you try a relative URL it falls apart.

Comment: I get a TS error `Type 'URLSearchParams' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
(property) URL.search: string`

Answer (score 1):

The object you have labeled `url_params` is described by the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) as:

> An options object containing any custom settings that you want to apply to the request.

It then goes on to list the properties you can include there.

`pagingindex` and `pagingresults` are not among them.

The query string is part of the URL. If you want to put data there, then put it **in the URL**.

```
const url_object = {
  url: `https://t1.testing.com/test/api/v1/blog?pagingindex=0&pagingresults=10`,
  url_params: {
    method: "POST"
  }
};
```

You may wish to use [the URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to construct the URL (it will handle escaping for you).

Comment: To be clear, the call to `fetch` should be `fetch(url_object.url, url_object.url_params)` if that object is to be used correctly. I know that wasn't part of the question, but for future readers who may not know how the OP was using that might pass that object verbatim to `fetch` and wonder why it doesn't work.

Comment: Yea i know that, when i pass it like you did it wokrs fine, but i dont want to hardcode it like that because it will need to be dynamic. I will try it with URL object.