# Fetch package is not able to fetch any data from the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch-api

I am working on a react js project and needs to fetch the data from the API.

I am using the `fetch()` to get the data.
Here, is my code.

```
fetch('https://sandboxapi.ampcome.com/api/gokhana/restaurant/categorized', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'WqQg2jqLWVIO5JBmQ1LYHU8w41FdzLEsCB6yP1Tw2AFHf2w5KWRkMBV8KAgY6Kl5'
  },
  qs: {
    geopoint: {
      near: {
        lat: 12.9699,
        lng: 77.6499
      },
      maxDistance: 50,
      unit: 'kilometers'
    },
    categories: ['trending', 'newaddition', 'popular'],
    outlettypes: ['restaurant', 'foodcourt'],
    clientapp: 'gokhanacustomer'
  }
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

Everything is fine, but this return the empty array.
There is a lot of data but it returns an empty array.

I tried the same with `axios` and it fetches data, I am unable to figure out the exact issue in `fetch()`

I need to compare the working of `axios` and fetch that is why I need to test it by both the ways.

Comment: Why do you need fetch at all? See,f or example: https://medium.com/@shahata/why-i-wont-be-using-fetch-api-in-my-apps-6900e6c6fe78

Comment: "fetch package" do you mean native `fetch` or which package exactly is your question about?

Comment: sorry it's native fetch

Comment: You are using `qs` property to pass query string params. Read this question plz [how to pass query string params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038857/setting-query-string-using-fetch-get-request)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko that solution actually worked fine for me, but the new problem arose, using both `axios` and `fetch` I am getting incomplete data from the API.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848651/api-fetches-incomplete-data-from-the-server-in-react-js-project