# how to pass query strings to get requests with fetch api

Tags: vuejs2, fetch, query-string, vuex

so im dispatching an action after login and using a getter to retrieve credential information that is used to initiate another fetch request. the request is going to the server correctly, and the getter is returning the appropriate data, however `req.query` on the server just returns `[object Object]`. this is the code:

**getter in component:**

```
  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('user/setFriends', {email: this.userInfo.email})
  },
  computed: {
 ...mapGetters('user', {
   userInfo: 'user_info'
  })
}
```

**actions:**

```
async setFriends ({
commit
}, email) {
  try {
    let request = new Request(`http://localhost:3000/users?id=${encodeURIComponent(email)}`)
    await fetch(request)
    await (r => r.data)
    await (r => commit('setFriends', r))
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.r)
  }
}
```

**route handler**

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.query.id)
});
```

**other attempt at fetch request**

```
  var url = new URL('http://localhost:3000/users')
  var params = {
    id: email
  }
  url.search = new URLSearchParams(params)

  await fetch(url)
```

i also read this link [Setting query string using Fetch GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038857/setting-query-string-using-fetch-get-request) when consulting how to write query strings with fetch. any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that the payload when dispatching the action does not need to be passed as an object, instead of passing of

```
created () {
this.$store.dispatch('user/setFriends', {email: this.userInfo.email})
},
```

simply the value

```
created () {
this.$store.dispatch('user/setFriends', this.userInfo.email)
},
```