# how to get data from response from fetch javascript request

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I make fetch request in javascript . It is fetching data when I seed console it show me data. but when
I try to alert it in then function it displays empty. it show alert promptly with page load. I think it alerting before request response

Here is my javascript code

```
fetch("https://01b4e41e6262.ngrok.io/api/get_schedule_orders/" + gUser.getData().id).then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
        alert(res)
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should be converting to `res.json` or `res.text` to get the content from response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pure Javascript fetch() method to java Servlet, how do i get and pass data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029283/pure-javascript-fetch-method-to-java-servlet-how-do-i-get-and-pass-data)

Comment: there are many, many, many Stack Overflow questions about how to access data in the response to `fetch`. which of them have you researched and why did they not solve your particular problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fetch()` returns a `Promise` initially, so **res** is initially a promise, either resolved or rejected.
Then `res.json()` again returns a promise and not the value directly (You may verify this by doing a `console.log(res)` in the first `then()`, there in the prototype you will see `json()`, which is again Promise based.

That's why we chain promises by doing `return res.json()` and get our data in the second promise resolve and in case of rejection `catch()` callback is invoked.

```
fetch("https://01b4e41e6262.ngrok.io/api/get_schedule_orders/" + gUser.getData().id).then(res => {
    if (res.status>=200 && res.status <300) {
      return res.json()
    }else{
      throw new Error();
    }
}).then(data=>console.log(data))
 .catch(err=>console.log('fetch() failed'))
```

UPDATE: your API is returning an empty array.

Please check the API params.

[image: API call result]

Comment: @Bilal arshad: The above code handles your error as well and works beautifully in all scenarios. Do rate the accept the answer. Thanks :) God Bless and Happy coding

Comment: I am trying this but not working ```fetch("https://01b4e41e6262.ngrok.io/api/get_schedule_orders/" + gUser.getData().id).then(res => {
  if (res.status===200) {
   return res.json();
  
  }
 }).then(data=> {
  $scope.schedule_orders = data.data;
  alert(JSON.stringify(data.json()))
 });```

Comment: Check whether the API is working fine or not. Try console.log() in your catch() block. Mean while I will see where the problem may be :)

Comment: I checked it, you API is actually returning an empty array. Everything is fine with the code.

Comment: in the preview section i see that ```0: {id: 10, devy_user_id: 129731,…}
created_at: null
data: "{"paymethod_id":1,"business_id":76,"delivery_type":"1","driver_tip":0,"delivery_zone_id":6569,"delivery_datetime":null,"location":RPM\"},\"tag\":\"home\"}"}"
devy_user_id: 129731
id: 10
schedule_date: "2020-12-12 21:06:00"
updated_at: null```

Comment: hmmm. I see. I think I figured it dear brother. Let me debug.

Comment: Replacing this gUser.getData().id by a devy_user_id's value in url returns array with values. See the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mvjy9e4a/ . You only need to figure our your query parameter correctly and it will work fine i-e , the last part of the url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225875/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-bilal-arshad).

Comment: Do let me know if it is working fine now :) Do rate and accept in case you learned anything new. For others to also benefit from :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The **Fetch API** initiates a chain of two `Promises`.

- the first promise retrieves the data from the server
- the second promise resolves the retrieved data (using `.text()`, `.json()` etc.)

**Example (using `async / await` syntax):**

```
const getScheduleOrders = async (gUser) => {

  const response = await fetch('https://01b4e41e6262.ngrok.io/api/get_schedule_orders/' + gUser.getData().id);
  const scheduleOrder = await response.text();
  await window.alert(scheduleOrder);
}
```