# How to pass an argument to a function in my backend using .fetch()? ReactJS + Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So I want to pass an integer argument to a function in my backend and have it return the data. I've been looking through the documentation and it seems like there might not be a way for me to pass an argument via the code I currently have. I just want second opinions before I consider using a different approach.

Frontend:

```
//is there a way for me to pass num to req in the backend?
newMarker = (num) => {
      fetch('/api/getMarkers')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(mark => this.setState({ markers: mark }))
  }
```

Backend:

```
//function where argument needs to be passed to, used in the request below
const fillNewMarker = async function fillNewMarker(num){
  let temp;
  let data;
  await populartimes(markers[num].placeID)
  .then(out => {data = out; temp = 'Currently ' + data.now.currently + ' full.'})
  .catch(() => {temp = 'There is currently no data available.'});
  markers[num].busy = temp;
}

//request
//i need num to be passed to req here
app.get('/api/newMarker', async (req,res) => {
    await fillNewMarker(req);
    console.log('Retrieve Data For New Marker Complete')
    var mark = markers;
    res.json(mark);
    console.log('Sent Markers');
    console.log(markers);
})
```

I've been working for quite a while so my brain is a little bit fried, there might be a really obvious solution that I have missed - if so, I apologize for my ignorance. Help is appreciated! TIA :)

Fix Attemp #1:

```
//Front end
  newMarker = (num) => {
      fetch('/api/newMarker', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(num) // body data type must match "Content-Type" 
        header
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(mark => this.setState({ markers: mark }))
  }

//method call via button
onButtonClick(){
  this.newMarker(6)
  //6 for testing
}

//backend
app.get('/api/newMarker', async (req,res) => {
    console.log('Request received')
    await fillNewMarker(req.body.num);
    console.log('Retrieve Data For New Marker Complete')
    var mark = markers;
    res.json(mark);
    console.log('Sent Markers');
    console.log(markers);
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting query string using Fetch GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038857/setting-query-string-using-fetch-get-request)

Comment: Hm not exactly, I tried implementing what the answer suggested with the URLSearch params but I get the problem where my request isn't even received.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an argument to fetch in the form of an object like

```
const response = await fetch('/api/getMarkers', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(num) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
mark = await response.json();
this.setState({ markers: mark })
```

On backend receive the argument as `req.body.arg_name`
,In your case it would be `req.body.num`

Comment: will the argument be passed as the req argument in my backend?(in my post). I tried only inserting the object you wrote to the code I posted as fetch's second param but it did not work :(

Comment: did you try with req.body.num

Comment: I did. it seems that the request is not even being called after I added the second parameter to fetch. I added a console.log statement to the very beginning of the request and it isnt printing. I added my exact code to my post, please have a look, thank you :)

Comment: Note: I have also tried using the exact code you gave and making my function in the frontend an async - still no luck :/ request is not recieved.