# pass parameters to url fetch request javascript

Tags: jquery, reactjs, ajax, get, fetch

Hello i'm trying to make a get request in react

with JQuery i used to do something like this

```
$.get("Run",{ pr: "takeData", name: "Bob"}, function (o) {
                   console.log(o)
             
            });
```

i tried doing something like this

```
fetch("https://localhost:44347/Run?{
      pr:"takeData",
    name:"Bob"
    }) .then( res => res.text())
   .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
   });
```

but id didn't worked,instead i had to do it like this

```
fetch("https://localhost:44347/Run?pr=takeData&name='Bob'") .then( res => res.text())
   .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
   });
```

and it worked, but i can't figure out how to pass the "pr" and the "name" parameters without having to type them directly in the url can someone help me?

Comment: This github issue might help you https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/256

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting query string using Fetch GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038857/setting-query-string-using-fetch-get-request)

Answer (score 2):

You can create URL and URLSearchParams objects to create your request without writing the fields in the URL by hand.

```
var url = new URL("https://localhost:44347/Run");
url.search = new URLSearchParams({ pr: "takeData", name: "Bob"});
fetch(url).then( res => res.text())
       .then((data) => {
         console.log(data);
     });
```

Comment: Please at least look for duplicates for such obvious questions...

Answer (score 0):

You can use templates literals for that see this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Here is an exemple :

```
const myString = `https://localhost:44347/Run?pr=${varPr}&name=${varName}`
```

Another way is to add strings like this :

```
const myString = "https://localhost:44347/Run?pr=" + varPr + "&name=" + varName
```