# Passing variable to fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch, next.js, spotify

I'm fetching from Spotify and I'm trying to add a query param if the user has made a country choice. I create a `const` and return a set of query params depending on this choice.

I keep getting the "only absolute URLs are allowed" error but, as far as I can tell, all the options I've tried have been with absolute URLs.

I've tried hardcoding it, I've tried a ternary operator in the template literal, I've tried various combos of using strings and creating URL objets, as found in threads [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038857/setting-query-string-using-fetch-get-request).

There's another string interpolation for context.params.word that also uses a regex, but that works just fine.

Here's my current code:

```
const spotifySearchUrl = () => {
    if (reduxStore.choices.country) {
      return new URL(
        `${context.params.word.replace(/#(.*)/, "")}&type=track&market=${
          reduxStore.choices.country
        }`
      );
    } else {
      return new URL(`${context.params.word.replace(/#(.*)/, "")}&type=track`);
    }
  };

const songsRes = await fetch(
  "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + spotifySearchUrl,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
      },
    }
  ).then //...cont
```

Comment: I think you need to invoke the function. `"https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + spotifySearchUrl(),`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const songsRes = await fetch(
  "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + spotifySearchUrl(),
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
      },
    }
  ).then //...cont
```