# searchFilter with using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is the assignment of our university. I tried to add the useEffect to improve my small toy-project to have searchFilter
but it says

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined**

on useEffect/setSearchFilter part

This was the previous situation of this problem.
I feel disaster for this problem holding this for more than 2 days

/[Error image][1]

Can anyone help me with this?

````
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);
  const [userid, setUserid] = useState('');
  const [searchFilter, setSearchFilter] = useState('');
  const inputChanged = (event) => {
    setUserid(event.target.value)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=react')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      setDatas(data.items)
    })
  },[])
  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchFilter(
      datas.full_name.filter((result) =>
        result.name.toLowerCase().includes(userid.toLowerCase())
      )
    );
  }, [userid, searchFilter]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Repositories</h1>
        <input 
          id="searchInput"
          type="text" 
          placeholder="search" 
          name="search" 
          value={userid} 
          onChange={inputChanged}
        />
        <button onClick={(e) => setSearchFilter(e.target.value)}>Search</button>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>URL</th>
          </tr>
          {datas.map((data, index) => 
           <tr key={index}>
             <td>{data.full_name}</td>
             <td><a 
                    target="_blank" 
                    href={data.html_url}
                    >
                      {data.html_url}
                  </a>
            </td></tr>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;```



https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67761971/searchfilter-with-using-react-hookuseeffect-usestate/67762090#67762090





  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuubM.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to filter the array of data on the "full_name" parameter - hence you run the `filter()` function on the array.
2. You don't need the search button if you're filtering as the user is
   typing (since you are using useEffect)

Here's the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [userID, setUserID] = useState('');
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);


  //Fetch data when mounted
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=react')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      setData(data.items)
    })
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
      let result = data.filter((d) =>
      d.full_name.toLowerCase().includes(userID.toLowerCase())
    )
    setSearchResults(result);
  }, [userID, data]);


  const inputChanged = (event) => {
    setUserID(event.target.value)
  }
  
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Repositories</h1>
        <input 
          id="searchInput"
          type="text" 
          placeholder="search" 
          name="search" 
          value={userID} 
          onChange={inputChanged}
        />
        {/* No need for search button if searching using input (useEffect will trigger when typed) 
        <button onClick={search}>Search</button> */}
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>URL</th>
          </tr>
          {searchResults.map((data, index) => 
           <tr key={index}>
             <td>{data.full_name}</td>
             <td><a 
                    target="_blank" 
                    href={data.html_url}
                    >
                      {data.html_url}
                  </a>
            </td></tr>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Ideally, you would want to handle the loading state and the error state as well.

Comment: I have also changed a few variable names as per standard. The original code had `searchFilter` as a string, whereas it should be `searchResults` as it is an array of the data after filtering. Your button component was being clicked and `event.target.value` was being set to the searchFilter. If you want to search after a user clicks, you don't need the useEffect hook.

Comment: "Always keep hooks above the rest of the function code" is ***not*** part of the Rules of Hooks, please check those rules again.

Comment: Oh my bad @DrewReese. I always thought the rule "Only Call Hooks at the Top Level" meant that they should be declared first before any other code. I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work instead of your second `useEffect` hook if you want to filter on `full_name`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setSearchFilter(
        datas.filter((result) =>
            result.full_name.toLowerCase().includes(userid.toLowerCase())
        )
    );
}, [userid, searchFilter]);
```