# fetch request with different parameters on every click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

Im using an API and I fetch 9 pictures every time from said API. the API can display "pages", meaning if a "page=1" parameter is passed in the request I get the first 9  pictures from the database. "page=2" gives me the next 9 pictures and so on.

I want to have 2 buttons so on every click I get the next 9 pictures. I tried to do so using the API parameter change but haven't had much luck.

I ran across this thread:

[Setting query string using Fetch GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038857/setting-query-string-using-fetch-get-request)

but either it doesnt help me or I dont understand it enough.
Thanks!

my code is below:

```
const Home = ()=>{

let pageNumber = 1;

const [photosData, SetPhotosData] = useState([])
const url = `https://pixabay.com/api/?key=25540812-faf2b76d586c1787d2dd02736&per_page=9&page=`

const getImages = async()=>{
    try {
        const response = await fetch (url+pageNumber)
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error();
        }
        const responseObj = await response.json();
        const allPhotosData = responseObj.hits

        SetPhotosData(allPhotosData)
    } 
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}


 useEffect(()=>{
    getImages();
  },[])

const getNextPage = ()=> {
    pageNumber++;
    console.log(pageNumber);
    getImages();
}


const getPrevPage =()=>{
    pageNumber--;
    console.log(pageNumber);
    getImages();
}
return(
<div>
    <button onClick={getPrevPage}>prev</button>
    <button onClick={getNextPage}>next</button>

    <br/>

    {photosData.map(singlePhotoData=>
        <img 
        key={singlePhotoData.id}
        src={singlePhotoData.largeImageURL}
         />)}
</div>
)
```

}

export default Home;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pageNumber` will reset to `1` everytime you set a new state with `SetPhotosData`. You could fix this by using `useRef`.

```js
const pageNumber = useRef(1);

...

const response = await fetch(url + pageNumber.current);

...

const getNextPage = () => {
  pageNumber.current++;
  console.log(pageNumber.current);
  getImages();
};

const getPrevPage = () => {
  if (pageNumber.current < 2) return;
  pageNumber.current--;
  console.log(pageNumber.current);
  getImages();
};
```

Note that we also check if the `pageNumber` is not lower than `2` before decreasing it and calling the api to prevent the api from throwing a error, saying it has no page `0`

Comment: Thanks! that did it! nice to learn a new hook too :)