# Convert curl auth to Javascript fetch API call

Tags: javascript, curl, async-await, fetch

```
$ curl https://api.goclimate.com/v1/flight_footprint \
  -u YOUR_API_KEY: \
  -d 'segments[0][origin]=ARN' \
  -d 'segments[0][destination]=BCN' \
  -d 'segments[1][origin]=BCN' \
  -d 'segments[1][destination]=ARN' \
  -d 'cabin_class=economy' \
  -d 'currencies[]=SEK' \
  -d 'currencies[]=USD' \
  -G
```

This is the api: https://api.goclimate.com/docs

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? You're expected to show some research effort or attempt at solving the problem yourself, when submitting a question to SO.

Comment: I tried with Fetch, async/await but I receive an error 404 or 401. Of course my api key is correct. It's two days that I'm trying to resolve this issue

Comment: We can't tell what went wrong with your attempt to convert it to fetch if we can't see your attempt. Please read [ask], in particular the part about providing a [mcve].

Comment: It would also be useful to know if you were using `fetch` in the browser (where (a) there is a useful Network tab in the developer tools that shows exactly what request you are making and (b) it is subject to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and will be making a [Preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request))) or `fetch` in Node.js or `fetch` somewhere else.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038857/setting-query-string-using-fetch-get-request

Answer (score -1):

Your question posted are not that clear, but this answer may help you, try to using online CURL converter tools like [this](https://curlconverter.com/). from that tool you will get the result like below code, hope this answer help you.

```
fetch('https://api.goclimate.com/v1/flight_footprint?segments[0][origin]=ARN&segments[0][destination]=BCN&segments[1][origin]=BCN&segments[1][destination]=ARN&cabin_class=economy&currencies[]=SEK&currencies[]=USD', { 
headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('YOUR_API_KEY:')
}});
```

If you still have problem, make sure your API-KEY are correct, and try to read official documentation of Javasript for fetching APIs.