# Django-Ajax "Uncaught ReferenceError: FOO is not defined"

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am new to AJAX. A want to make a call to a django view to update item quantity and change number on the page.
I have a template

```
...
{% for item in items %}
  <div id="quantity">{{ item.quantity }}</div>
  <button onclick="updateQuantity('parts/quotes/ajax/increase-item/')">+</button>
...
<script>
  function docReady(fn) {
    if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "interactive") {
      setTimeout(fn, 1);
    } else {
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
    };
  };

  docReady(function() {

    function updateQuantity(url) {
      fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        }
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        document.getElementById("quantity").innerHTML = data;
      });
    }

  });
</script>
```

And a view:

```
def increase_quote_item_ajax(request):
    is_ajax = request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
    if is_ajax:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            item = QuoteItem.objects.get(id=pk)
            item.quantity += 1
            item.save(update_fields=['quantity'])
            return JsonResponse({'data': item.quantity})
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'Invalid request'}, status=400)
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('Invalid request')
```

But when I click on + button I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: updateQuantity is not defined
```

Why isn't my function registering?

**UPDATE**:

Per David's advice:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <span>{{ item.quantity }}</span><button class="increase-button"  data-foo=""{{ item.get_increase_url_ajax }}"">+</button>

...

<script>
    const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('quantity-button');
    for (const button of buttons) {
      button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        fetch(e.target.dataset.foo, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
          },
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          button.previousSibling.innerHTML = data['quantity'];
        });
      });
    }
</script>
```

What's a proper way to pass the `id` in the fetch request to the django view? I don't think I am supposed to do that in headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`updateQuantity` isn't defined in global (window) scope, only in a specific function.  So the `<button>` can't invoke it directly like that.

One approach would be to move the `updateQuantity` function out of that anonymous function and into global scope:

```
<script>
  function updateQuantity(url) {
    //...
  }
</script>
```

Since all this does is *define* a function then it shouldn't need to wait for the `DOMContentLoaded` event.  If you *do* want/need to wait for that event, you can manually assign the function to the `window` object:

```
<script>
  docReady(function() {
    window.updateQuantity = function (url) {
      //...
    };
  });
</script>
```

Alternatively, instead of calling the function directly in the `<button>` markup at all, assign a click handler where you define the function.  For example, if you give the `<button>` an `id`:

```
<button id="update-button">+</button>
```

Then when defining the function you can use that `id` (or any selector you like, this is just for example) to attach the click handler to the button:

```
<script>
  docReady(function() {
    const url = 'parts/quotes/ajax/increase-item/';

    function updateQuantity() {
      //...
    }

    document.querySelector('#update-button').addEventListener('click', updateQuantity);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I see where my problem is with the scope. Then a follow up question: since i have a for loop creating multiple buttons, how do I pass an {{ item.id }} to updateQuantity function to pass it to Django view?

Comment: @Viktor: You could include values on the button as `data-*` attributes, and then fetch those attribute values from the button that raised the event.  [Here's a quick demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1sxdcqa6/) for using a `data-*` attribute.  As an aside... If you're outputting elements with the same `id` *in a loop* then you're going to run into additional problems, as `id` values are supposed to be unique.

Comment: I've updated the code (see above), but what's the proper way to send the id back to the django view (not in the header, I assume)

Comment: @Viktor: That may depend on your back-end code.  How is it *expecting* that value?  On the query string?  In a form?  In a JSON request body?  Something else?  Note also that the original code and the original problem/question didn't really have anything to do with that.  If you're encountering a *new* issue unrelated to the original problem then that would likely merit a new question.

Comment: What I mean is I can send ithe id in headers ```"pk": e.target.dataset.foo,```, and extract it back in the view with ```request.headers.get('pk')```. But that doesn't seem to be an intended way. What is the appropriate fetch dictionary for that?

Comment: @Viktor: Perhaps you're looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038857/setting-query-string-using-fetch-get-request)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255717/discussion-between-viktor-and-david).