# ASP MVC 3 complex multi parameters kno

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

in my previos question [Asp MVC 3 json complex object not initialize properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334268/asp-mvc-3-json-complex-object-not-initialize-properties/8334710#8334710)
My mistake was in JSON convert from Knockout and after one more time with `JSON.stringify(data).`
Now evering working fine with one parameter,
but I wonder about if I need send to MVC controller two or more parameters one of them  is knowckout `data = ko.toJSON(viewModel);` variable other one is some text.

```
var settings = ko.toJSON(viewModel);

var parameters = JSON.stringify({ id : *"guid"*, data : settings });

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/KioskAjax/SaveSettings/',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: parameters,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert('ok');
                    }
                });    


 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveKiosksSettings(Guid id, GlobalData data)
        {
            return Json(false.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

In this example **id** is getting value, but GlobalData parameters is null again, 
i think this is because I use JSON.stringify again, but how build correct JSON for controller call if I have knowckout object ?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ko.toJSON(myObject)` does a `ko.toJS(myObject)` and then a `JSON.stringify(myObject)`.

So, you could choose to use `ko.toJS(myObject)` to get a clean copy of your data and then `JSON.stringify` it with your other data, as you are already doing.