# jquery serialize error

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have login form which i want to send via ajax using serialize but its send data in wrong format like this

```
Array
(
    [form] => uname=as
    [upass] => amitpatilasas
    [action] => login
)
```

This HTML

```
    <form action="#" method="post" name="login" id="login" rel="external" class="ui-corner-all">

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
             <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" value="" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
             <input type="password" name="upass" id="upass" value="" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>

            <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
            <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="button" id="cancel" data-theme="d">Cancel</button></div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="button" id="dologin" data-theme="a">Login</button></div>
            </fieldset>
            </div>

    </form>
```

This is javascrip

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "server.php",
      data: "form="+$("#login").serialize()+"&action=login",
      success: function(responce){
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `"form="+` part. Then it'll work.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "server.php",
      data: $("#login").serialize()+"&action=login",
      success: function(responce){
```

At least it will give you this output;

```
Array
(
    [uname] => as
    [upass] => amitpatilasas
    [action] => login
)
```

Comment: Hey Emre, thanks man...it worked...and i cant believe how i can be this much DUMB...y i didnt analyzed it properly :P

Comment: Sorry dont get me wrong...i read ur answer first accepted it,commented and then i saw next post...i commented that, accepted too...i didnt knew that it will remove first "acceptance" i am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: No problem. If other answer is more satisfying for you, you can accept that instead of mine. It's your choice. I was just curious about your reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
"form="+$("#login").serialize()+"&action=login"
```

Given `someuser` and `somepassword`, will send this data:

> form=uname=someuser&upass=somepassword&action=login

Notice the double equals sign, which is wrong, and which is why you're getting the error.  If you drop the `form=` part, then you'll get a correct query string.

However it is weird to send in query string parameters in the *body* of the message rather than the URL.  It'd make more sense to structure your code this way:

```
var loginUrl = "server.php"
    + "?"
    + $("#login").serialize()
    + "&action=login"
    ;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: loginUrl,
  success: function(response){
    // ...
  },
  error: function(response){
    // ...
  }
);
```

... or send in the body as JSON rather than as query string parameters.

[To find out how to serialize to JSON, see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery).

Comment: Merlyn, if you send JSON, jQuery automatically serializes it and convert it to querystring formation. Best practice for this situation is using `data` property. Amit is doing right.

Comment: @EmreErkan: "if you send JSON, jQuery automatically serializes it and convert it to querystring formation" - it doesn't put it in the URL tho (at least [not via my experimentation](http://jsfiddle.net/cqadk/)).  If it automatically tears apart JSON (even manually formatted) and turns it into a query string *in the body of the message*, that would be strange.  I'm talking about AJAX best practices, not jQuery.  Making your AJAX API expect a query string in the body of the message is weird.

Comment: @EmreErkan: My googling for "jQuery JSON query string" seems to bring up if you assign an *array* to `data`, that [jQuery will turn that into a query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308846/serialize-json-to-query-string-in-javascript-jquery).  That's not what the OP is doing here.

Comment: From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):data
Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Comment: @EmreErkan: I'm not arguing that jQuery doesn't automatically do this.  My experiments agree with your statements there.  My whole point is that having a serialized query string in the body is weird, no matter whether jQuery seems to prefer it or not.  If your additional processing options can get jQuery to append it to the URL on POST requests too, that sounds like a good idea here, and a better idea than manually building the URL like my code is doing.