# How can I convert an object to a query string?

Tags: javascript

I want to stringify an object into a query string.

For example,

```
{ hello: '123', goodbye: "789" }
```

Would give me...

```
hello=123&goodbye=789
```

Comment: It should be doable with loop and join. I don't think I have come across built-in JS function to do this, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialize object to query string in JavaScript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308846/serialize-json-to-query-string-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an excellent URL library, [URL.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/) which works pretty much as you describe for queries.

For your example, the code would be:

```
URI().addSearch({ hello: '123', goodbye: "789" }).toString()
```

This produces the result with a pre-pended `?`, but it comes in extremely handy for constructing & manipulating real URLs.

Comment: +1 for answering the actual question.

Answer (score 4):

If case if you use jQuery in your project you don't need a lib for this:

```
$.param({ hello: '123', goodbye: "789" })
```

But since there is no jQuery tag, take a look at `Barney` answer, this is probably what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code sample for simple cases:

```
var params={ hello: '123', goodbye: "789" },
    pairs=[];
for (var key in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        pairs.push(key+"="+encodeURIComponent(params[key]));
    }
};
var qs=pairs.join("&");
```

For more complex scenarios you might want to use a library like URLjs as suggested in other replies.