# How to pass a JSON string to API Gateway as query Parameter

Tags: json, velocity, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

How can i pass a JSON object like `{val: 1}` to my Lambda function as a query parameter?
Following [Standardized way to serialize JSON to query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872658/standardized-way-to-serialize-json-to-query-string#answer-15873977) i URL-encoded my JSON object and requested the following: `mysite.com/path?json=%7B%22val%22%3A%201%7D`

As [requestTemplates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#stagevariables-template-reference) i tried the following two options

1. `"json": "$input.params().querystring.json"`
2. `"json": "$util.parseJson($input.params().querystring.json)"`

But i got this error message:

> {"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected
>   character (\'v\' (code 118)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT
>   entries\n at [Source: [B@37a2970e; line: 1, column: 47]"}

If i do not encode the query string so: `mysite.com/path?json={"val":1}` i get a 400 error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your mapping template is producing no valid JSON, you have to wrap the key/value pair in curly braces
2. I guess you do not want to wrap the value in quotes, it will be a string and no object otherwise
3. You can use `$util.urlDecode` to decode URL encoded strings

Your mapping template should look like this:

```
{"json": $util.urlDecode($input.params().querystring.json)}
```

For `mysite.com/path?json=%7B%22val%22%3A%201%7D` this mapping template will result in the following JSON:

```
{
  "json": {
    "val": 1
  }
}
```

---

If you want the querystring JSON to be passed on the root level to your Lambda function use this as a mapping template:

```
$util.urlDecode($input.params().querystring.json)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you

Comment: you save my day ! Thank you :)