# how to send a Json object to a dialog from the parent using dialog API in Office365

Tags: json, office365, office-addins, office-js, office-app

I am new to office 365 word JavaScript API. I am trying to send a Json object to a dialog from the parent using the dialog api. But I couldn't find a better solution for that. I have found it is possible to send a Json object from the dialog to the parent using below code snippet.

```
Office.context.ui.messageParent
```

can someone give me a good solution with a code snippet to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like that

In parent web page (the actual add-in) javascript code

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, options, function(result) {
    var dialog = result.value;
    dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, function(args){
        dialog.close();
        var json = JSON.parse(args.message);
        //do what ever you need to do...

    });
});
```

*NOTE*: for the sake of simplicity I omitted "error checks" if callback function receive error result. You should take care of that as well.

The web page that is opened at `url` will have a function for pushing back the json object after representing it as a string

```
var asString = JSON.stringify(myObj);
Office.context.ui.messageParent(asString);
```

Of course the webpage opened in the dialog window must also reference Office.js.
Here is the documentation link for this so-called dialogAPI https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui

**Edit:**

*the original question is to send data from parent to children*

If you need to send info to the page opened in dialogAPI. I suggest your append query parameters to `url`. You can stringify your Json object and pass it. This is not very clean thought.
[Standardized way to serialize JSON to query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872658/standardized-way-to-serialize-json-to-query-string)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this is not what I have asked. Your example show send Json data from the dialog to the parent. But I need to send Json object, from the parent to dialog.

Comment: @NishMJ Sorry, I have update my answer. I have kept the original answer because it may be useful for others.

Comment: Thank you, But I do not understand how to get the URL parameters in the dialog. could you please show me an example how to get the json object in the dialog, sent from parent?

Answer (score 0):

You can send JSON data or object back to your parent easily.

This code snippet should be in your child page's(Dialog page) JS file.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    // The Office initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnLogin').click(submit);
        });
    };
    function submit() {
        // Get and create the data object.
        var email = $('#txtEmail').val();
        var password = $('#txtPassword').val();

        var data = {
            email: email,
            password: password
        }

        // Create the JSON and send it to the parent.
        var json = JSON.stringify(data); 

        Office.context.ui.messageParent("json");
    }    
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

Find section "Passing information to the dialog box".

Two primary ways:

- Add query parameters to the URL
- Store the information somewhere that is accessible to both the host window and dialog box, e.g. local storage