# Sending an array of json objects to web api, how to format the url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have written asp.net web-api project with following api-s:

Controller Method:                        Uri:

GetAllItems:                          /api/items    (works)

GetItem(int id)                             /api/items/id  (works)
and

GetListOfItem(IEnumerable<Items> items)                       /api/items/List of items (doesn't work)

The function is similar to this (don't care about logic)

```
public IHttpActionResult GetByArray(IEnumerable<Book> bks)
    {
        var returnItems = items.Select(it => it).Where(it => it.Price < bks.ElementAt(0).Price || it.Price < bks.ElementAt(1).Price);
        if (returnItems == null)
            return NotFound();
        else
        {
            return Ok(returnItems);
        }
    }
```

I am using postman to send requests and following requests works correct

```
http://localhost:50336/api/items/
http://localhost:50336/api/items/100
```

but not

```
http://localhost:50336/api/items/[{"Owner":"MySelf","Name":"C","Price":151},{"Owner":"Another","Name":"C++","Price":151}]
```

How should i format the last request where i have a list of items in json format in order to get it works?

Comment: Pass the JSON in the body of the request, not the URL..

Comment: [Url encode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872658/standardized-way-to-serialize-json-to-query-string) the object.

Comment: Can you illustrate it with en example? I am quite new in the web world so illustrating with an example is the best way for me to understand in this case :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to decorate your method with a `HttpPostAttribute` and `FromBodyAttribute`:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetByArray([FromBody]IEnumerable<Book> bks)
{
}
```

Then send the json as post body.

---

Your Postman shoud look like this:

[image: Postman]

Comment: Can you specify with an example how should i do it. What i want to know is how should the url command be written  since the one below doesn't work  My methos has now the signature according to [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult GetByArray([FromBody]IEnumerable<Book> bks)  and the command sent from postman is http://localhost:50336/api/items/[{"Owner":"MySelf","Name":"C","Price":151},{"Owner":"Another","Name":"C++","Price":151}]     The url command is invalid according to the answer i get from postman logs

Comment: Your welcome. Feel free to accept the answer then (click on the grey hook to the left) @user1520812

Answer (score 2):

Specifically for

```
GetListOfItem(IEnumerable<Items> items)
```

[FromBody] is definitely best option.

In case you are using primitive types you can do following:

```
GetListOfItem([FromUri] int[] itemIds)
```

And send request as:

```
/GetListOfItem?itemIds=1&itemIds=2&itemIds=3
```

Comment: Haven't come across `FromUri` before, +1