# How can I parse complex query strings generated by jQuery.ajax() in Perl?

Tags: perl, parsing, cgi, query-string

[`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) encodes complex JavaScript objects into a query string like this:

```
?a[b][]=1&a[b][]=2&a[c]=3
```

I would like to decode this into a Perl data structure like this:

```
{ a=>{ b=>[1,2], c=>3 } }
```

PHP does this by default. Is there a way to also do it in a Perl CGI script? Not necessarily using CGI.pm; I can install any library I want.

So far I can only decode one-dimensional arrays because the CGI module's `param()` function can return an array.

Comment: [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON), [JSON::XS](http://p3rl.org/JSON::XS)...

Comment: @choroba That's not JSON.

Comment: I know but isn't it possible to switch to JSON instead?

Comment: @choroba [This is something jQuery does to pass around JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

Comment: Do you control the JavaScript code? If so, convert your object to a JSON string, URL encode it, and send that. JSON is a language-independent standard, while jQuery's `.param` method is not. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15872658

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Better yet, skip all the URI encoding, query parsing, query param size limits, and security issues of sending data via GET and POST JSON.

Comment: @Schwern Even better!

Comment: @Schwern Actually, I think you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered submitting your data as JSON instead? It's simply a question of replacing

```
data: data
```

with

```
data: JSON.stringify(data)
```

You could even switch to a `POST` to avoid URI-encoding, URI-decoding and query size limits (although POST semantics are different than GET semantics).

```
method:      "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
data:        JSON.stringify(data)
```

---

Anyway, the following should do the trick:

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveVal );
use List::Util  qw( pairs );  # 1.29+
use URI         qw( );

my $url = URI->new('?a[b][]=1&a[b][]=2&a[c]=3', 'http');

my %data;
PAIR: for ( pairs( $url->query_form() ) ) {
   my ($k, $v) = @$_;

   my ( @k, $push );
   for (my $k_ = $k) {  # Basically C<< my $_ = $k; >>
      s/^(\w+)//
         or warn("Can't handle key $k\n"), next PAIR;

      push @k, $1;
      push @k, $1 while s/^\[(\w+)\]//;
      $push = s/^\[\]//;

      $_ eq ""
         or warn("Can't handle key $k\n"), next PAIR;
   }

   if ($push) {
      push @{ DiveVal(\%data, @k) }, $v;
   } else {
      DiveVal(\%data, @k) = $v;
   }
}
```

Versions of Perl older than 5.16 need a workaround. Replace

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveVal );
push @{ DiveVal(\%data, @k) }, $v;
```

with

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveRef DiveVal );
push @{ ${ DiveRef(\%data, @k) } }, $v;
```

Note that the format is ambiguous<sup>[1]</sup>. For example, the following two expressions produce the same result (`a[0][x]=3`<sup>[2]</sup>):

```
jQuery.param( { a: [      { x: 3 } ] } )

jQuery.param( { a: { "0": { x: 3 } } } )
```

My code will reproduce the former. Numeric keys are always considered to be array indexes.

---

1. Another reason to use JSON.
2. Some escaping removed for readability.

Comment: Consider turning that into a module?

Comment: There's no spec, but the [implementation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/5f35b5b406ae7d504de86a3f0a5647b2fdf4f2af/src/serialize.js#L55) is pretty short. Of course, it's changed several times over the years...

Comment: @ikegami I tried your function, but it says: `Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at test.pl line 25.` which is the line: `push @{ DiveVal(\%data, @k) }, $v;` I can't say I understand what you are doing there so can you please help me correct it?

Comment: @ikegamy also shouldn't the line `for (my $k_ = $k)` be: `for (my $_ = $k)` I think that's just a typo.

Comment: If one could do `my $_ = $k;`, there wouldn't be any need for `for` at all. `for (my $k_ = $k) { ... }` is used as an alternative to `my $_ = $k; ...` meaning it creates a lexically-scoped `$_` that's a copy of `$k`.

Comment: Neat, I did not know about this. Unfortuantely the original problem still stands, the undefined value as ARRAY reference.

Comment: @soger, huh? What version of Perl and Data::Diver do you use? Do you have better luck with `push @{ ${ DiveRef(\%data, @k) } }, $v;`? (Don't forget to import `DiveRef`.)

Comment: Also, any reason you're not switching to JSON?

Comment: @ikegami DiveRef did it, thank you. I have perl 5.14.2 so not the newest, that may be the problem, but I just installed Data::Diver from CPAN so that's the latest version. Update your response if you wish so it will work for more people. The reason I'm not switching to JSON is because my company extensively uses jquery and php but some tasks are better suited for perl so and I need interoperability.

Comment: That explanation makes no sense. Using JSON actually increases interoperability. JavaScript, PHP and Perl all handle JSON expertly. (`my $data =decode_json($json);`) Unlike this broken format you are asking about.

Comment: Well I didn't want to write a novel into the comment section but basically what I'm doing is I'm writing a specialized cache layer between already existing pages that display information on a map (based on postgres notifications it knows when the cache needs to be refreshed) and it's just easier to make my perl code compatible than to rewrite the other pages. And this is not the first time I needed something similar and your code is not that complicated so why not. I know there are better solutions but it's a huge already running project so I can't just rewrite anything I want.

Comment: That makes no sense at all. You're obviously changing how you're calling the Perl script, so we're only talking about changing new code or code you're already changing. And even if the calls to `.ajax` are all over the place (which thye shouldn't be), it's trivial to apply `s/data: \K(\w+)/JSON.stringify($1)/g` to your files.

Answer (score 1):

PHP interprets a query string like `foo[]=123&foo[]=234&foo[]=345` differently than all of the Perl web frameworks. I once built a PHP plugin for Mojolicious and had to work out a lot of those differences. You can find a summary of those differences and some working code (working for up to 2-level hashes, anyway) to convert Perl params to PHP-style params [here](https://metacpan.org/source/MOB/MojoX-Plugin-PHP-0.05/lib/MojoX/Template/PHP.pm#L349). Perhaps you could adapt it for your use case.