# How to send an array of objects in params with axios?

Tags: javascript, post, parameters, axios

I need to send in such format

```
/api?filters=[{"values":["f"],"fieldName":"dossierNumber"}, {"values":["ddddd"],"fieldName":"territorialSubdivision"}]
```

I've tried to use `qs` param serializer but what I get is

```
pageSize
    5
pageNumber
    1
filters[0][values][0]
    f
filters[0][fieldName]
    dossierNumber
```

How can I send the params as a plain array with objects inside of it

Comment: qs is provifing proper `form-urlencoded` format. Why is that a problem?

Comment: @charlietfl, because the backend doesn't see the parameters, and I cannot modify the backend

Comment: Does api not accept a POST for complex data like this?

Comment: @charlietfl, yes it does not

Answer (score 0):

Try using `encodeURI`

```
encodeURI(JSON.stringify([{"values":["f"],"fieldName":"dossierNumber"}, {"values":["ddddd"],"fieldName":"territorialSubdivision"}]))
```

Comment: it works partially, it removes the & sign in parameters and adds {} around them

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/50012536/8017385

Comment: @acetheninjs, it didn't help, not my case