# Serialize an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, underscore.js

I have a function that queries a Rest API. The function call looks like:

```
var filters = [
    {field: "TestField", "params[value]": "VIDEO"},
    {field: "TestField2", "params[value]": "IMAGE"},
];

this.query({limit: 10, text:"Test", filters: filters});
```

I want to build a query string that looks like:

```
?limit=10&text="Test"&filters[0].field=TestField&filters[0].params[value]=VIDEO&filters[1].field=TestField2&filters[1].params[value]=IMAGE
```

What is the best/fastest way to do that in JavaScript regarding the filters array?

Comment: I see you're using Underscore, but are you also using jQuery?

Comment: Okay, and what is `params[value]`? That code definitely runs?

Comment: My question is: What is the best way to build the query string that I posted in my question.

Comment: You can't use `params[value]` as a key of an object literal. Either use a string `"params[value]"`, or use EcmaScript6 computed property names `[params[value]]`.

Comment: Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/, but note the ... not. You might be better off serializing the data to JSON.

Comment: Like @Oriol said, that isn't valid JS. That's my confusion.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308846/serialize-object-to-query-string-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: Ah, that was a copy&paste error with the params[value] -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is your friend:

```
var filters = [
    {field: "TestField", "params[value]": "VIDEO"},
    {field: "TestField2", "params[value]": "IMAGE"},
];

var qs = filters.map(function(filter,i){
    return "filters[" + i + "].field=" +
            encodeURIComponent(filter.field) +
            "&filters[" + i + "].params[value]=" +
            encodeURIComponent(filter["params[value]"]);
}).join("&");
```