# Mapping object to key=value string in one line

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to convert this object:

```
{
    lang: 'en-us',
    episode: 12
}
```

To a string with the following format?

```
"lang=en-us&episode=12"
```

Much like mapping an object to a query string, where each property is a query parameter.

I can do it like this:

```
var parameters = [];
for(var prop in obj)
   parameters.push(prop + '=' + obj[prop]);
return parameters.join('&');
```

But I was looking for a **one-line** solution. Is this possible?

**PS**: I cannot use *jQuery* and any of it utility functions. The solution must be in pure JavaScript.

Comment: ... Put it into a function? Unrelated, but if the values can be arbitrary, make sure you make them into URL-safe strings.

Comment: A "one-line" requirement in JavaScript doesn't make much sense, as you can just put all the code in the same line. In what manner would the code be a one-line solution?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308846/serialize-object-to-query-string-in-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) array:

```
var data = {"lang": "en-us", "episode": 12};
var str = Object.keys(data).map(function (key) { 
  return "" + key + "=" + data[key]; // line break for wrapping only
}).join("&");
console.log(str);
```

With ES6, this becomes even more terse:

```
var data = {"lang": "en-us", "episode": 12};
var str = Object.keys(data).map(key => `${key}=${data[key]}`).join("&");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
var myObj ={"lang": "en-us", "episode": 12};
var str = Object.keys(myObj).map(key => key+"="+myObj[key]).join("&");
```

Whether or not this is any more readable is another question :)

Answer (score 3):

- ### `Object.entries` (ES6)

  [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns `[key, value]` pairs, so we can destructure and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the pairs directly into `${key}=${value}`:

  ```
  Object.entries(params).map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`).join('&');
  // "lang=en-us&episode=12"
  ```

- ### `URLSearchParams`

  For the specific use case of query strings, use [`URLSearchParams.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/toString):

  ```
  let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(params);

  searchParams.toString();
  // "lang=en-us&episode=12"
  ```

  [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) provides an interface with [common utility methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#methods), e.g.:

  ```
  searchParams.get('episode');
  // "12"
  ```

  ```
  searchParams.sort();
  // "episode=12&lang=en-us"
  ```

  ```
  searchParams.set('episode', 123456);
  // "episode=123456&lang=en-us"
  ```

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers work perfectly,

However I've found that you can use `URLSearchParams` for the same thing...

```js
var myObj = {keyOne: 'keyOneValue', keyTwo: 'keyTwoValue'};
var queryParams = new URLSearchParams(myObj).toString();
console.log(queryParams);
// keyOne=keyOneValue&keyTwo=keyTwoValue
```

> see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Answer (score 0):

If the value contains equalTo (=) symbol, the accepted solution will not work.

**Example**

```
key1=a,key2=b,keyc=keyof=thec
accesskey=absdsfdfsa===
```

**Solution:**

Better to use Regex,

```js
const a =
  'AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1';

  const output = {};

  a.split(';').forEach((v, i) => {
    const [key, value] = v.split(RegExp(/=(.*)/));
    output[key] = value;
  })

  console.log(output);
```

output
Note: AccountKey contains == in value

```
{
  AccountName: 'devstoreaccount1',
  AccountKey: 'Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==',
  DefaultEndpointsProtocol: 'http',
  BlobEndpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1',
  QueueEndpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1',
  TableEndpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1'
}
```