# Is there an equivalent to Ruby on Rails' to_query method in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails you can use [to_query](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/to_query) to convert a hash into a string suitable for use as a URL query string.

For example:

```
{ :name => 'David', :nationality => 'Danish' }.to_query # => "name=David&nationality=Danish"
```

Is there an equivalently easy way to do this in jQuery or javascript?

Comment: This has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308846/serialize-object-to-query-string-in-javascript-jquery  For some possible solutions.

Comment: The [the first hit](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=jquery+to_query&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) according to the googlies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) function.

```js
var query = $.param({ name: 'David', nationality: 'Danish' });
console.log(query);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```