# How to use json object keys in api url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

can anyone tell me if there is a way to use json object key values in url?
Like when we use a open api like openweathermap we give its url some parameters like city name ect ,and they send relative data to that value, I want to know how they do it.

Comment: Do you have any specific example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serialize object to query string in JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308846/serialize-object-to-query-string-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: to Ranga Dewasinghe .. i am trying to make a shopping website where my all products data are stored in a json file like this  fashion={ productone={name,ect,category},producttwo{name,ect category} }  they all have same key called category with different values like men, kids, ect . i want to pass object key category in fetch api url so whenever i change its value through useState i can fetch same category products in my application , but i don't know how to pass a object key in url

Comment: to salvino : sory this won't work for me

Comment: you can use `post` request, try googling `post with fetch`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```js
function jsonToQueryString(json) {
  return '?' +
    Object.keys(json).map(function(key) {
      return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(json[key]);
    }).join('&');
}


const baseUrl = 'http://example.com';
const params = {
  lat: 'x',
  long: 'y',
  limit: 50
};
console.log(`${baseUrl}${jsonToQueryString(params)}`)
```