# remove url parameters with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string, expression

I am trying to use the youtube data api to generate a video playlist.

However, the video urls require a format of:

```
youtube.com/watch?v=3sZOD3xKL0Y
```

but what the api generates is:

```
youtube.com/watch?v=3sZOD3xKL0Y&amp;feature=youtube_gdata
```

So what I need to do is be able to select everything after and including the ampersand(&) and remove it from the url.

Any way to do this with javascript and some sort of regular expression?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738351/recommendation-for-javascript-url-manipulation-library-api/3215670#3215670

Comment: possible duplicate of [querystring encoding of a javascript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

What am I missing?

Why not:

```
url.split('?')[0]
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine!

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a scenario in which this short solution doesn't work?

Comment: @goldylucks there is none, this is a perfectly adequate solution!

Comment: exactly half a decade later, why isn't this the answer?

Comment: I agree, this is way better than my juvenile answer from nearly a decade ago.

Comment: It will also remove URI fragments if any, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 29):

Hmm... Looking for better way... here it is

```
var onlyUrl = window.location.href.replace(window.location.search,'');
```

Comment: That's my specific case to reload the page without the parameters:   window.location.assign(window.location.href.replace(window.location.search,''));

Answer (score 25):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/SjrqF/

```
var url = 'youtube.com/watch?v=3sZOD3xKL0Y&feature=youtube_gdata';

url = url.slice( 0, url.indexOf('&') );
```

or:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/SjrqF/1/

```
var url = 'youtube.com/watch?v=3sZOD3xKL0Y&feature=youtube_gdata';

url = url.split( '&' )[0];
```

Answer (score 11):

Use this function:

```js
var getCleanUrl = function(url) {
  return url.replace(/#.*$/, '').replace(/\?.*$/, '');
};

// get rid of hash and params
console.log(getCleanUrl('https://sidanmor.com/?firstname=idan&lastname=mor'));
```

If you want all the href parts, use this:

```js
var url = document.createElement('a');
url.href = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=URL#search-results-close-container';

console.log(url.href); // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=URL#search-results-close-container
console.log(url.protocol); // https:
console.log(url.host); // developer.mozilla.org
console.log(url.hostname); // developer.mozilla.org
console.log(url.port); // (blank - https assumes port 443)
console.log(url.pathname); // /en-US/search
console.log(url.search); // ?q=URL
console.log(url.hash); // #search-results-close-container
console.log(url.origin); // https://developer.mozilla.org
```

Answer (score 6):

```
//user113716 code is working but i altered as below. it will work if your URL contain "?" mark or not
//replace URL in browser
if(window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1) {
    var newUrl = refineUrl();
    window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/"+newUrl );
}

function refineUrl()
{
    //get full url
    var url = window.location.href;
    //get url after/  
    var value = url = url.slice( 0, url.indexOf('?') );
    //get the part after before ?
    value  = value.replace('@System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"]','');  
    return value;     
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
window.location.replace(window.location.pathname)
```

Answer (score 3):

> No *splits..* :) The correct/foolproof way is to let the native browser [BUILT-IN functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) do the heavy lifting using `urlParams`, the heavy lifting is done for you.

```js
//summary answer - this one line will correctly replace in all current browsers
window.history.replaceState({}, '', `${location.pathname}?${params}`);
```

```js
// 1 Get your URL 
let url = new URL('https://tykt.org?unicorn=1&printer=2&scanner=3');
console.log("URL: "+ url.toString());

// 2 get your params
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
console.log("querys: " + params.toString());

// 3 Delete the printer param, Query string is now gone
params.delete('printer'); 
console.log("Printer Removed: " + params.toString()); 

// BELOW = Add it back to the URL, DONE!
___________
```

**NOW Putting it all together in your live browser**

```js
// Above is a breakdown of how to get your params
// 4 then you simply replace those in your current browser!! 
window.history.replaceState({}, '', `${location.pathname}?${params}`);
```

[Sample working Javascript Fiddle here](https://codepen.io/draw/pen/zYoqyKJ?editors=1111)
[image: working sample code to replace query substring and query params]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RegEx to match the value of `v` and build the URL yourself since you know the URL is youtube.com/watch?v=...

http://jsfiddle.net/akURz/

```
var url = 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=3sZOD3xKL0Y';
alert(url.match(/v\=([a-z0-9]+)/i));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am using this:

```
stripUrl(urlToStrip){
        let stripped = urlToStrip.split('?')[0];
        stripped = stripped.split('&')[0];
        stripped = stripped.split('#')[0];
        return stripped;
    }
```

or:

```
    stripUrl(urlToStrip){
        return urlToStrip.split('?')[0].split('&')[0].split('#')[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For example we have:

```
example.com/list/search?q=Somethink
```

And you need use variable url like this by **window.location.href**:

```
example.com/list/edit
```

From url:

```
example.com/list/search?q=Somethink
example.com/list/
```

```
var url = (window.location.href);
    url = url.split('/search')[0];
    url = (url + '/edit');
```

This is simple solution:-)

Comment: Please give an appropriate solution, this works only with /search patterns, what if i want to do these * values or say any value?

Answer (score 0):

I am using following line to remove all url parameters without reloading page

```
window.history.replaceState(null, '', window.location.pathname);
```