# How to fetch url of application?

Tags: javascript

Hi i have a change password page after reseting the password it should redirect to the home page. Thia is my URL for change password page.

https://localhost:9003/store/change-password?code=0a05a6d6-2298-4b62-9687-7deae15951e4

i got this using this in javascript.

var url = window.location.href;

I want only this much URL "https://localhost:9003/store" how can i get it?

Regards,
Priyanka

Comment: If this will not be dynamic till change-password, you can split it and get the desired string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove url parameters with javascript or jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651990/remove-url-parameters-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way. but this method will work for you.

```
function() {
    var href = window.location.pathname;
    var regex = "/[A-Za-z0-9\s]+";
    var strArray = href.match(regex);
    if (strArray && strArray.length) {
        return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + strArray[0];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var url = window.location.origin + (window.location.pathname.indexOf("/")>=0 ? "/" + window.location.pathname.split("/")[1] : "");
alert(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

use This :

```
document.location.origin
```

Comment: this will return "https://localhost:9003"  , but op wants "https://localhost:9093/store"

Answer (score 0):

it will be done by location's api easily.

```
    var host = location.origin;
    var path = location.pathname;
    var firstPath = path.split("/")[0];
    var url = host + "/" + firstPath;
```

the url is what you want.Also you can get the first pathname via Rexg.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = "https://localhost:9003/store/change-password?code=0a05a6d6-2298-4b62-9687-7deae15951e4";

var u = url.substr(0,url.indexOf('/',23));

alert(u); 

console.log(u);
```

Comment: It works as long as the hostname is localhost. But when it is significantly longer or shorter, the fixed 23 offset is not safe to use anymore.

Comment: Hmm I think you are correct but I guess we are dealing with a static url in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below syntax:

```
var anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
anchorTag.href = "https://localhost:9003/store/change-password?code=0a05a6d6-2298-4b62-9687-7deae15951e4";
anchorTag.text = "Link";
var hrefText = anchorTag.href;
var url_1 = anchorTag.origin;
var url_2 = hrefText.substr(anchorTag.origin.length, hrefText.indexOf('/'));
var url = url_1 + url_2;
console.log('url = ', url);
```

Refer to the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/2en9ejn4/).