# Backbone Send Post data encoded as query string

Tags: rest, backbone.js, http-post, url-encoding

I'm creating a backbone app that's connecting to a RESTful backend. When I call save() on a model, it sends the post data as stringified JSON:

```
{"firstName":"first","lastName":"last","Email":"email@gmail.com"}
```

but my server expects it to be formatted like a querystring:

```
firstName=first&lastName=last&Email=email@gmail.com
```

is there a way to have backbone send it differently?

Comment: If that's what your backend is expecting then it is **not** RESTful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Backbone doesn't provide anything like this out of the box.
But is easy to override and customize it to your needs.

Have a look to the source code:
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html

and check out that calling `save`, it will trigger a `sync` call in the background.

So what you need is to override `Backbone.sync` function with your own.

I would modify the part of:

```
if (!options.data && model && (method == 'create' || method == 'update')) {
      params.contentType = 'application/json'; 
      params.data = JSON.stringify(model.toJSON());
}
```

with

```
if (!options.data && model && (method == 'create' || method == 'update')) {
      params.contentType = 'application/json';
      params.data = $.param(model); // <-- CHANGED 
}
```

Notice I'm using [jQuery param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

If you want to use a custom function, check this question:
[Query-string encoding of a Javascript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object)

**[Update.]**
No need to modify directly. Better override it with your own function 'Backbone.sync'
Check the "TODO" example of the Backbone repository. It has a `localStorage.js` file that overrides Backbone.sync function https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/tree/master/examples

Comment: I thought about doing this but I want to avoid editing the backbone source, I guess I could replace the Backbone.sync function with a modified one when my app starts, rather than directly editing the backbone.js file. Is it common to 'override' backbone methods like this?

Comment: I just tried overriding the Backbone.sync function when my app loads, it doesn't work because the methodMap array that sync uses is defined locally in the Backbone module, so my new sync function doesnt have access to it. To fix this Id have to edit backbone.js and set it on the Backbone object so that I could reference it outside of backbone.js: `var methodMap=[...]; Backbone.methodMap = methodMap;`, so I might as well change sync in there. But I dont want to touch backbone.js, it just seems wrong. e.g. it'd make it hard to upgrade backbone, would have to find all domain specific code first.

Comment: I updated the answer. Maybe you try to override Backbone before is loaded?

Comment: You definitely shouldn't continue to send the "application/json" header if you're not actually sending JSON. The data that's being sent is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem at work and the Backbone.emulateJSON didn't work for me either.  With some help I was able to come up with this workaround.  We overrode the Backbone.ajax function and changed the contentType to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and used $.param to properly serialize the data.

```
Backbone.ajax = function() {
    if(arguments[0].data && arguments[0].contentType == "application/json"){
        arguments[0].data = $.param(JSON.parse(arguments[0].data));
        arguments[0].contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    }
    return Backbone.$.ajax.apply(Backbone.$, arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you,try:
http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateJSON

Comment: Not really what I want, using emulateJSON will send post data like this: `model="{'firstName':'first'}"`

this will just stick the JSON in a quesrystring, rather than encoding all values as a querystring.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by overriding model's sync function:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    "sync": function(method, model, options) {
        if (method == "update" || method == "create") {
            options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
            options['data'] = $.param(this['attributes']);
        }
        var arguments = [method, model, options];
        return Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solutions, see :

1. I use

   Backbone.emulateJSON = true;
2. I write the "update" case:

   ```
   options.url = "/user/"+Math.random(1, 1000);
   options.type = "POST";
   //.1/2 WORK
   //options.data = (model instanceof Backbone.Model)?model.toJSON():{};
   options.data = model.toJSON();
   break;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Backbone.sync uses the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function, so we can modify the jqXHR or data that is sended to the server (via beforeSend).

```
var oldSync = Backbone.Model.prototype.sync;
var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'test.json',

    defaults: {
        id: 1,
        foo: 'test'
    },

    sync: function (method, model, options) {
        // options are passed to the jQuery.ajax
        _.extend(options, {
            emulateHTTP: true,
            emulateJSON: false,
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                // settings.data is a body of our request.
                if (_.isString(settings.data)) {
                    // settings.data is a JSON-string like '{"id":1, "foo":"test"}'
                    settings.data = Backbone.$.parseJSON(settings.data);
                }

                settings.data = Backbone.$.param(settings.data);
                // settings.data is 'id=1&foo=test'
            }
        });

        oldSync.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});

var model = new SomeModel();
model.save();
```

Actually we can create a mixin! :)

Comment: Code only answers [are usually frowned upon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258673/2596334). Try adding [an explination or code comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269981/2596334). Thanks.

Comment: Or, put another way: Good answers accompany code samples with an explanation for future readers. While the person asking this question may understand your answer, explaining how you arrived at it could help countless others.

Comment: Sorry, guys. I've updated the answer. My English is poor, i know it, but i do my best :)