# fetch data in $_POST variable in angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

i wish to post data to a php file using angularjs. I referred to the following link:
 http://www.cleverweb.nl/javascript/a-simple-search-with-angularjs-and-php/

i tried the same example given in the link but the data is posted in JSON format. I want the data in $_POST variable. how do i do that?
 here's my code:

search.js

```
   function SearchCtrl($scope, $http) {
        $scope.url = 'php/search.php'; // The url of our search
        // The function that will be executed on button click (ng-click="search()")
        $scope.search = function() {
            // Create the http post request
            // the data holds the keywords
            // The request is a JSON request.  i want the data in $_POST
            $http.post($scope.url, { "data" : $scope.keywords}).
            success(function(data, status) {
                $scope.status = status;
                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.result = data; // Show result from server in our <pre></pre> element
            }).
            error(function(data, status) {
                $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                $scope.status = status;         
            });
        };
}
```

search.php

```
   <?php
// The request is a JSON request.
// We must read the input.
// $_POST or $_GET will not work! **but i want it to work!**
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $objData = json_decode($data);
// perform query or whatever you wish, sample:

include 'connect.php';
mysql_select_db($database,$con);  
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `product`';
$result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error()); 
$cnt = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $nm = $row['name'];
    //print_r($nm.' ');
    if($objData->data == $nm) {

        $cnt++;
    }
}

if($cnt == 0) {
    echo ' Sorry, no match!';
}
else {
    echo ' I have found what you\'re looking for!';
}
```

how do i solve it?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-make-angular-js-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload

Answer (score 2):

Just normal PHP:

```
$_POST['title'] or $_POST['content'];
```

You can do it ;-)

This is an anwser to the comment beneath the post beneath.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, you can access the variables in the php file as you normally would.

```
$http.post("yourpagehandler.php", {
    // Values you with to send to php page
    "title": $scope.title,
    "content": $scope.content
}).success(function(data, status) {
    // Values returned from php handler will be in data

}).error(function(data, status) {
    $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
    $scope.status = status; 
});
```

Comment: it seems that i am too stupid to do this. Would someone tell me how to access the posted variables in php?

Comment: json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)["title"]; will access the data at "title".