# Pass array of data from Angular $http POST

Tags: http, rest, post, angularjs

I need to pass an array of object from my Angular application to a .Net web service with Nancy framework.

I tried this :

```
function TestCtrl($scope, $http){
    $scope.postTest = function(){

        var data = [obj1, obj2, obj3];

        $http({
            url: 'myURL',
            method: "POST",
            data: data,
            headers: {
                     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            }
        }).success(function(data){
            alert("done");
        });
    }
}
```

But server send 500 Internal server error.
I don't know why it doesn't work. I'm not an expert web service expert but I think it's a serialization problem.

Can someone help me?

Comment: what  data format your webservice is expecting ?

Comment: My web service expects JSON

Comment: If you are facing AngularJS specific serialization problem, then httpParamSerializerJQLike is what you need. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852190/angularjs-get-ajax-call-with-array-parameters

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-make-angular-js-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload), you're right, this is about serialization. [Angular doesn't automatic serialize the data for you](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1743), you need to parse the data before sending it:

```js
...

$http({
  url: 'myURL',
  method: "POST",
  data: $.param(data),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
  }
})...
```

If you don't use jQuery, you'll need to roll your own `$.parse`. There is a [snippet here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object) or you could [adapt jQuery implementation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/serialize.js#L38-L71).

Comment: Thank for your answer, but $.param doesn't work, an error says it's not defined

Comment: This is a jQuery call. AngularJs doesn't provide a solution out of the box :(. [Here is something about it](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1743). If you don't use jQuery, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/querystring-encoding-of-a-javascript-object) is a snippet to achieve the encoding. I'll update the answer.

Comment: it works fine for a simple object, but with an array of objects, it doesn't work. However, I think now it's a server-side problem...

Answer (score 21):

```
angular.toJson(data)
```

should work in place of

```
$.param(data)
```

Comment: This should be a comment?

Answer (score 8):

[fauverism](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721040/fauverism) is right, you can use angular.toJson(data). Not instead, but before $.param though.

```
function TestCtrl($scope, $http){
$scope.postTest = function(){

    var data = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
    var jsonData=angular.toJson(data);
    var objectToSerialize={'object':jsonData};

    $http({
        url: 'myURL',
        method: "POST",
        data: $.param(objectToSerialize),
        headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    }).success(function(data){
        alert("done");
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

you can use $httpParamSerializer or $httpParamSerializerJQLike

```
$http(
    url: 'myURL',
    method: "POST",
    data: $httpParamSerializer(data),
)
```