# Using Angular.js $http.post with Codeigniter WITH CSRF enabled

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, angularjs, csrf

I'm trying to post via Angular.js to a CodeIgniter controller in an application that has CSRF enabled (on the same domain). With jquery, I would just add the token like so:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
data: {
    csrf_token: $("input:hidden[name='csrf_token']").val()
}
```

I've added the post values and headers in Angular.js, but no joy. Anybody know how to accomplish this?

```
var postData = { name:"csrf_token", value: $("input:hidden[name='csrf_token]").val() };
$http.post('myCIcontroller',postData,{headers: {'csrf_token': $("input:hidden[name='csrf_token']").val()}}).success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
var postData = $.param({csrf_token: $("input:hidden[name='csrf_token']").val()});

$http.post('myCIcontroller', postData, {headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}).success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
});
```

More info here:
[How can I post data as form data instead of a request payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-make-angular-js-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var postData = { csrf_token: $("input:hidden[name='csrf_token]").val() };
```

This basically does the same as your jquery ajax call. You might also want to get rid of the `headers` in `$http.post()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That makes the post look like: {"csrf_token":"839e01fd6186fd839f5ff70f995c0f5f"} but it needs to look like: csrf_token=c30c272623b8c02b7c938d81dfb00862. I tried setting  headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} but still no joy.

Comment: @user2011685 If you configure `$.ajax()` to make POST calls, the `data` is also turned into request body, not querystring.