# how to change post['Content-Type'] in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i want to change  post['Content-Type']  in angularjs so i use

```
  app.config(function($locationProvider,$httpProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;        charset=UTF-8';
 });
```

and the event is

```
     $http.post("http://172.22.71.107:8888/ajax/login",{admin_name:user.u_name,admin_password:user.cert})
        .success(function(arg_result){

            console.log(arg_result);


        });
};
```

however the rusult is

```
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
{"admin_name":"dd"}
```

what i want is

```
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
 admin_name dd
```

so what i should do?

Answer (score 28):

Try like:

```
var serializedData = $.param({admin_name:user.u_name,admin_password:user.cert});

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://172.22.71.107:8888/ajax/login',
    data: serializedData,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }}).then(function(result) {
           console.log(result);
       }, function(error) {
           console.log(error);
       });
```

Comment: thank you very much !it works well!but i do not not the function of "$.param"

Comment: `$.param` is a jQuery function for serializing form data into a string. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/ . It's required to serialize your JSON like this when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: @XzAngular, you can use *JSON.stringify(requestObject)* instead of *$.param*. It does not require jQuery.

Comment: Very nice! I had problems with the preflight options request didn't respond with the appropriate headers but post did. Using the code above and changing it from "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" to "text/plain" fixed this for me. Default the content type would be "application/json"

Answer (score 6):

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
        .config(function ($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] =  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
        })
```

Comment: Spent about two hours of my life on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OP is using `Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so  you need to use [$httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike) to change post data from JSON to string

note: there is no *data* property but is *params* property

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'whatever URL',
            params:  credentials,
            paramSerializer: '$httpParamSerializerJQLike',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
```

Additionally, you can inject the serializer and use it explicitly with *data* property

```
.controller(function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
....
$http({
        url: myUrl,
        method: 'POST',
        data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(myData),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
     });
```

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at this:
[How can I post data as form data instead of a request payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-make-angular-js-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)

Alternatively, you could do the following:

```
$http.post('file.php',{
        'val': val
    }).success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
```

PHP

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$val = print_r($post->val,true);
```

Comment: Yes it does. Provide your issue as a fiddle or plunkr and I will have a look

Comment: This is an incomplete solution, if you want to specify a different content type besides the default, you must declare it inside the http service. I am not saying your solution does not work or it does work, but that is not what was asked.