# pyramid not work with angular $http post

Tags: angularjs, pyramid, cornice

```js
$http({method: 'POST', url: 'http://localhost:5001/products', data: {token: $scope.product.token}}).success(
    function () {
        alert('success');
    }
);
```

In the pyramid side, request.POST show that NOVars: **Not a form request. Not an HTML form submission( Content-Type: application/json)**

I am using cornice to provide my api(/products) and I thinks it is pyramid's problem.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Angular sends the post body (data) as `application/json` while forms are normally sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Pyramid parses the body and let you access it in `request.POST` when it's encoded as a normal form.

It is not be possible to represent every data encoded the Angular way (json) as a key/value pair like is provided by pyramid API.

```
[
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4
]
```

## Solution on Pyramid side

It can be solved per view or globally

### Per view

This is the pyramid way and the most flexible way to handle this.

```
@view_config(renderer='json')
def myview(request):
    data = request.json_body
    # deal with data.
    return {
        "success" : True
    }
```

### Globally

Pyramid can most likely be set to assume a body encoded as `application/json` is an object and its properties be put in request.POST.

## Solution on Angular side

As with the pyramid side, it can be solved per request and globally.

### Per request

You need to send the data the way forms are normally sent:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: url,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  transformRequest: function(obj) {
    var str = [];
    for(var p in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
      }
    }
    return str.join("&");
  },
  data: xsrf
}).success(function () {});
```

### Globally

To send posts as form by default, configure the $httpProvider to do so.

```
angular.module('httpPostAsForm', [])
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.unshift(function (obj) {
     var str = [];
    for(var p in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
      }
    }
    return str.join("&");
  });
}]);
```

Then include this module in your app:

```
angular.module("app", ["httpPostAsForm"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS $http.post is different from jquery's. The data you pass is not posted as a form but as json in the request body. So your pyramid view can not decode it as usual. You have to either:

- directly access the request body and decode it in your pyramid view;
- or modify your angularjs code to post your data as form content : see [this other question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-make-angular-js-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)

Answer (score 1):

the answer is angular $post do OPTIONS request first and then do the POST request, get data form the request.json_body

Answer (score 1):

Use `req.json_body` if you post some json-decoded content. `req.GET`, `req.POST`, `req.params` only cope with from submissions.  Btw, $http -> ngResource -> restangular ...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting contenttype in $http, something like below.

```
 $http(
           {
               url: url,
               contentType: "application/json",
               data: data,
               method: method
           })
           .success(function (response) {
               successcb(response);
           }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) { errorcb(data); });
  };
```

Comment: by default content type is application/json in angular no need to specify

Comment: than check , that you are passing correct object to the post service , can you show your post service ?

Comment: my post service checks token params to decide whether the user got the permission to add a product, it works fine using curl

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the POST data this way:

```
query = json.loads(request.body)
```