# jQuery ajax request works, same AngularJS ajax request doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and trying to build front-end system that gets data from Wordpress.

On the back-end side everything seems to be set up properly and when I use jQuery ajax request it gets the data without problems.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: {
        action: 'getdataajax'
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

But when I try to do the same thing with AngularJS, it does not work. I'm trying to replicate the ajax request with code like this:

```
myApp.factory('productsData', function($http, $log) {
    return {
        getProducts: function(successcb) {
            return $http({ 
                method: 'POST', 
                url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 
                data: {action: 'getdataajax'}
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    successcb(data);
                    $log.info(data, status, headers(), config)

            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $log.warn(data, status, headers(), config)
            });
        },

    };
});
```

If I log it, it outputs 0. What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

P.S. Controller looks like this:

```
myApp.controller('ProductsController', function ProductsController($scope, productsData) {

    $scope.sortorder = 'name';

    // $scope.products = productsData.products;
    // $scope.products = productsData.getProducts();

    productsData.getProducts(function(products){
        $scope.products = products;
    });
});
```

Comment: How are you using this in your controller
?

Comment: Updated the post. I've tried different ways. Commented as well. None of them works. Sorry

Comment: Add it to the question please, pasting code in comments is rather ugly.

Comment: Seems that nobody else tried to use angular with wordpress. I made some server testing. Php responds properly. Also, if I hardcode the data into the factory - it works fine. To be honest, all of this is rather weird.

Comment: Can you use `console.dir(arguments)` to see all arguments and values in your success function?  In the networks tab in chrome dev tools you can see the request, are you getting the same data back?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the angularjs code, use `params:` instead of `data:`.

In jquery the object supplied to the `data:` config setting is converted to a query string (?key1=val1&key2=value2) unless you set `processData: false`. in angularjs, you have to use `params:` to get a query string, `data:` is sent as json or string.

Comment: Should note that this becomes req.query on the server side