# Angularjs $http not sending form data to the server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http

The below code works if I use jquery ajax but `$http` of Angular doesn't send any data to the server using the code below:

```
myapp.factory('startCampFactory',function($http,$q,$rootScope){
  return {
    startNewCampaign : function(){

      var e = $("input#email");
      var email = e.val();
      var campname = $("input#campaignname").val();
      var about = $("textarea#about").val();
      var tamt = $("input#targetamount").val();
      var edate = $("input#enddate").val();
      var invitees = $("input#invitees").val();
      var file_data = $("#file").prop("files")[0];
      var form_data = new FormData();     

      form_data.append("file",file_data);
      form_data.append("email",email);
      form_data.append("campaignname",campname);
      form_data.append("about",about);
      form_data.append("targetamount",tamt);
      form_data.append("enddate",edate);
      form_data.append("invitees",invitees);

      console.log(email+about+campname);

      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $http({
           method:'POST',
           url:'/startcampaign',
           data:form_data,
           headers:
             {
               'Content-Type'​ :'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
             }
        }).success(function(data,status,headers,config) { 
          $rootScope.$apply( function() { 
          deferred.resolve(); 
        });
     }).error(function(){
        $rootScope.$apply(function() 
          { 
            deferred.reject();
          }); 
     });
     return deferred.promise;
   }
});
```

Comment: How do you invoke this service? $http automatically return `Promise` you don't need to do that...

Comment: @rohit if you find the solution post that let others will know about it

Comment: I don't understand why this post has been downvoted : it's a common issue that can be found in web

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this :

```
.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
  this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(){
    })
    .error(function(){
    });
  }
}]);
```

Refer this link for explanation :

http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

Comment: Please refrain from posting a link-only answer since the link might be unavailable someday. Instead, you could digest the content and answer with your own words, and then cite the link as a reference.

Comment: @Tay2510 :  Made the changes. Thanks for your feedback. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck with this either, and ending up using jQuery.ajax (although I was using jsonp).

See [How can I post data as form data instead of a request payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-make-angular-js-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)

Perhaps "And the data passed should be converted to a string" is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

`data` in jQuery's `$.ajax` does not correspond to `data`in Angular's `$http.get/post`.  You may have to use `params` instead of `data` in Angular.  Have you looked at this:

[jQuery ajax request works, same AngularJS ajax request doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967307/jquery-ajax-request-works-same-angularjs-ajax-request-doesnt/18967966#18967966)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is occurring due to content type, remove the headers part or add

```
    contentType:false or 'multipart/form-data'

      $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:'url'
        data:formData,
        contentType:false,
        processData: false
    }).
    then(function(result) {
        alert(result);
    });
```

Comment: No, this code didn't work. Content-Type should be in headers (`headers:{ 'Content-Type': '...'} ` ) in angularjs. Also i'm not sure about processData.