# How to parse an Angular POST request in WebApp2

Tags: google-app-engine, angularjs, webapp2

How do I get data from my Angular POST request in Google App Engine WebApp2?  `self.request.body` returns a string, and `self.request.get(key)` returns nothing.

The Angular code that submits the POST is:

```
$http.post("/mail", {request_name: 'Test Name', request_body: 'Test Body'});
```

Then these two lines in my WebApp2 handler:

```
print "1:  " + self.request.body
print "2:  " + self.request.get('request_name')
```

Print this:

```
1:  {"request_name":"Test Name","request_body":"Test Body"}
2:
```

What is the best way get data from the POST body?  Or should I send the request differently?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Judging from your first print, it seems that Angular is sending the data in JSON format. Webapp2 will not parse this data for you. For your particular request, you can do:

```
import json
d = json.loads(self.request.body)
v = d.get(key)
```

If you want to be able to access the POST data using `self.request.POST.get(key)`, you probably need to submit the data as form data. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11443066/2021517) for more information about that.

Answer (score 0):

I always use self.request.get and able to get the data from GET/POST method, maybe you send the data in different format that only accessible by self.request.body?

Comment: Chrome dev tools says the request is `application/json;charset=UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 self.request.POST.get(key) # POST requests
 self.request.GET.get(key)  # GET requests
```