# Submit form to new window using AngularJS

Tags: html, forms, angularjs

Is there any way of submitting form data in a new window and using AngularJS. The traditional way of doing this stuff is by setting target attribute of form ? Is there a way of doing same using Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You are still able to submit your form to diferent `target` but it will only send the html form data - not the `angular` form data (which can contain more complex data structures than strings and numbers).

If you want to send the `angular` form data I would recommend using [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service;

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-make-angular-js-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload) for example