# Codeigniter + Angular Js: How to receive JSON data

Tags: php, json, angularjs, codeigniter, post

**This is the situation:**

I have a simple app made in Angular JS that comunicate with the server through an API made in codeigniter.

There is a login system in the app. When the user enter email and password, this data are sent to the server, if the email exist and the password match, it return true.

I have made many attempts but not figure out how can i do this properly.

**This is the code:**

**The form:**

```
<form role="form" method="post" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**This is the Angular js controller:**

```
 $scope.authorized = false;

 $scope.user = {};

 $scope.submitForm = function() 
 {
    console.log("posting data....");

    $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'http://127.0.0.1/api/main/login',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data : JSON.stringify({email:$scope.user.email, password:$scope.user.password})
    }).success(function(data) {
         console.log(data);

        $scope.authorized = data; 

        if ($scope.authorized) { $location.path("memberArea"); };        

    });

}
```

In the **codeigniter method** have tried many things.
Right now there is just this:

```
function login()
{
    print json_encode($_POST);
}
```

But i don't know if can receive the data into the $_POST because it seems to be empty.

**So the question is:**

How can i receive data in the codeigniter method?
Is better to send as JSON and then json_decode?
I have also tried json_decode($_POST, true);
But was null.
But if the data are not in $_POST where are?
I am little confused..

Thank you for help!

**EDIT:**

Thanks guys for reply.
That was one thing that have tried. But somehow is not working.
Now for example the method is like this:

```
function login()
{
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    var_dump($email);
    print json_encode($email);
}
```

But what is returned is a boolean false.

Comment: put this in controller `print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')));` and paste outcome pls.

Comment: Yes was that the key! i discover half an hour ago. I was going to make the answer. If you want to make, i will make your as correct answer!

Comment: glad to help johny :)

Comment: I think this is the best solution here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload

Answer (score 14, accepted):

thanks for the reply.
solution is as follows

```
$obj=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

you can test it by

```
print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46979306/receiving-an-object-as-an-ionic-parameter-to-a-php-controller?noredirect=1#comment80906165_46979306

Answer (score 3):

`$_POST` will be empty in CodeIgniter because it purposely empties it for security reasons. You need to use `$this->input->post();` instead.

[CodeIgniter Input Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$postData = $this->input->post();
```

It should give you an array with all the post data.

I also advise you to turn on XSS filtering.

Following is the documentation for the Codeigniter Input Class: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: @johnnyfittizio I don't know anything with AngularJS but can you try to change your data attribute of your call to: `data : {email:$scope.user.email, password:$scope.user.password}`

Comment: The most easy way is to pass the user object. data : $scope.user
In this case data will be sent as a json object. but how can i receive it in codeigniter?

Comment: By using the input class, Codeigniter should automatically perform a json_decode on the data you pass from your post.
Have you tried to set the contentType and or dataType to JSON in your ajax call?

Comment: Yes have set it (and edited question). But in the event i don't send data taken from a form, but fake string data. How can this be received in codeigniter. I think this is the point.

Comment: By the way Angular is great!

Comment: Are you still doing `$email = $this->input->post('email');` while still using `data : JSON.stringify({email:$scope.user.email, password:$scope.user.password})` ? This will definitely not work because you're sending a string but expecting an array which has a key named email.

Comment: But if i leave data : $scope.user how can i retrieve it in codeigniter?

Comment: If $scope.user is a JSON object, it will be translated into an array in Codeigniter when you use `$user = $this->input->post()`

Answer (score 1):

the data sent with the request is a name-value pairs so you should write some thing like that:

```
data : {"myformdata":JSON.stringify({email:$scope.user.email, password:$scope.user.password})}
```

and in code igniter you can recive the data :

```
$this->input->post("myformdata"); //should return what
                                  // that JSON.stringify returned
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this is already answered I quite often have this quick little utility included in many of my applications that need to accept both `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/json` POSTs.

```
if (strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'post') === 0 && stripos($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'], 'application/json') !== FALSE) {
    // POST is actually in json format, do an internal translation
    $_POST += json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
}
```

After that point you can now just use the `$_POST` superglobal as you normally would, all the JSON data will be decoded for you.