# Returning HTTP status codes in Codeigniter using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, codeigniter

I created a simple submit page using codeigniter and angular.js. How can I throw HTTP status codes after somebody clicked submit button, so the the user will know if it is successful or not, or any other reason why it failed?

BTW, I base my code in this post [Codeigniter + Angular Js: How to receive JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659632/codeigniter-angular-js-how-to-receive-json-data)

Comment: If it came to success callback, then it is succesful, if it come to error is not? Why do you want to know HTTP status code. For that you have to use then.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.success()` IMHO. Use `.then()` instead.

```
.then(function(resp){
    var $status = resp.status //http status code
    var $data = resp.data //data back from the server
});
```

If you're set on using `success`, then check out all the arguments for the `success` function:

```
success(function(data, status, headers, config)
```

As usual, [check the docs when you'er in doubt](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: do I need to do something in my controller where the data is submitted? Like sending HTTP code?

Comment: Explain why he should use `then()` instead of `success()`!

Comment: The `status` in the above indicates the response from the server, [Here's a list of those codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). You can return your own response with custom text by simply returning a json encoded array, as such: `echo json_encode(array('status' => 'OK', 'msg' => 'it went ok!'));`. Then in your angular you can access this like: `resp.data.status`

Comment: The reason I say to use `.then()` instead of `.success()` is due to the fact that a promise is returned from the `$http` call which can allow you to chain methods against it. In this particular case, it's a non issue, but in practice, it will be better as you'll be used to it for more complex tasks.