# Send a post request from angular to Codeigniter's controller

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, post

[image: Here I am sending post request to my manager/approveit controller]

Here I am sending post request to my manager/approveit controller ^^

And i am receiving the data like this in my controller manager's function approveit() like this

```
public function approveit(){
    //print_r($id);
    print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')));
    $this->input->post();
    echo "halalala";
}
```

But i am not even redirected to the page manager/approveit. I have seen answers like:-

[Codeigniter + Angular Js: How to receive JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659632/codeigniter-angular-js-how-to-receive-json-data)

[How can I post data as form data instead of a request payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)

and have applied them but they didn't work here, please tell me how to send post request from angular to my php CI controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you show the output of your browser console.

also, isn't there a typo in your code line 76

maybe it should be that:

```
data: {id: $scope.id}
```

and also can you write the promise callback and print in the console the output

.then(function(response)...);

Comment: I am getting "status: 200 OK" as response if I add .then(function(res){console.log(res)});   Also did "data: {id: $scope.id}" , still doesn't work.

Comment: I am getting id "12345" as output though from angular function.