# Convert $.param in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, url, param

Before I am using JQuery and I use this to send URL with parameter

```
window.location = myUrl + $.param({"paramName" : "ok","anotherParam":"hello"});
```

but with angularjS this does not work the same way

```
$scope.myButton = function() {
    $window.location.open = myUrl + $.param({"paramName" : "ok","anotherParam":"hello"});
};//Error: $ is not defined
```

can anyone help me how to do this in angularJs

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Comment: like this, www.test.com?option=ok

Comment: add jquery if you want to use jquery functions. otherwise you need to do it the old javascript way.

Comment: angular uses jquery lite - ultimately you might want an angular directive to handle when the button is clicked

Comment: I think you want something like `$location.path('xxurlxx')` but i am not sure about the parameter because i am not farmiliar with what you are trying to do with the `option`

Comment: read up here - what u need might be in it https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Comment: @ewizard, it is just a param name, how can I do that with $location.path

Comment: @Joakim - I don't want to use JQuery, I don't want it to mix up with angular.

Comment: Please have a look at this [ST question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-make-angular-js-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload) and answers

Comment: @przno yes this will work in sending params, but what I need is to open a tab because I am returning a jasperReport.

Comment: ah ok - so - `window.location.open` is supposed to open a new tab?

Comment: what is your routing like? I've used angular a bunch - not how u are trying to use it yet :) - but all the experience I have had with url params/angular, usually you have to set up a route (either in node/express...if that is what you are using) - and angular also has a routing system. I am still unclear as what your parameter signifies...you have said you want to open a new tab - how does your database data factor into your problem? Are you using a database?

Comment: @vintot jquery and angular js works perfectly fine with eachother, one does not go in the way of the other. I do however understand the feeling of not wanting to use both but it is still possible with no hassle at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are trying to create serialized representation of data like [$.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) does,

```
function serializeData( data ) { 
    // If this is not an object, defer to native stringification.
    if ( ! angular.isObject( data ) ) { 
        return( ( data == null ) ? "" : data.toString() ); 
    }

    var buffer = [];

    // Serialize each key in the object.
    for ( var name in data ) { 
        if ( ! data.hasOwnProperty( name ) ) { 
            continue; 
        }

        var value = data[ name ];

        buffer.push(
            encodeURIComponent( name ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( ( value == null ) ? "" : value )
        ); 
    }

    // Serialize the buffer and clean it up for transportation.
    var source = buffer.join( "&" ).replace( /%20/g, "+" ); 
    return( source ); 
}
```

and use this for your data serialization

Comment: how to use this function??

Comment: this function won't work if the data contains nested objects i.e: if you data is something like {foo:[{id:1, val:'test'},{id:2, val:'test2'}], bar:{test:'myTest'}} it won't work

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. If jQuery has this implemented, use it. Don't be too scary about mixing these libraries. [AngularJS does not replace jQuery.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23606512/878514)

Answer (score 36):

There's a built-in serializer in angular which mimics $.param():
[$httpParamSerializerJQLike](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

Comment: note that `$httpParamSerializer` and `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` are available since Angular 1.4

Comment: this should be the real answer

Answer (score 7):

AngularJs has jquery lite on its core so you can use angular.element.param() instead of $.param()

Comment: this is the best answer. writing code that already exists is not a good idea.

Comment: .param() isn't included in jQLite: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: this may work if you include jQuery anyway, as angular will use that, but with pure Angular (jQuery Lite) it throws 
TypeError: angular.element.param is not a function

Comment: Doesn't work. `Uncaught TypeError: angular.element.param is not a function(…)`

Comment: I have edited this answer to avoid the misinformation of jQuery lite containing `.param()`. Thanks for that clarification @AlexRoss!

Comment: I downvoted because it's not correct that "AngularJs has jquery lite on its core". Alex Ross makes this clear. Cabloo tried to edit the answer to correct the misinformation.

Answer (score 2):

I found this function useful for url serialization. Will also work for nested objects.

```
var param = function(obj) {

  if ( ! angular.isObject( obj) ) { 
    return( ( obj== null ) ? "" : obj.toString() ); 
  }
  var query = '', name, value, fullSubName, subName, subValue, innerObj, i;

  for(name in obj) {

    value = obj[name];
    if(value instanceof Array) {
      for(i in value) {

        subValue = value[i];
        fullSubName = name + '[' + i + ']';
        innerObj = {};
        innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
        query += param(innerObj) + '&';
      }

    } else if(value instanceof Object) {
      for(subName in value) {

        subValue = value[subName];
        fullSubName = name + '[' + subName + ']';
        innerObj = {};
        innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue;
        query += param(innerObj) + '&';
      }
    }
    else if(value !== undefined && value !== null)
      query += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&';
  }

  return query.length ? query.substr(0, query.length - 1) : query;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use $.param on the javascript object and pass it to either $resource or $http and it should work fine. One caveat though is ensure it is an object and not an array.

```
var badParam = {'name':'john',...}; // contains more properties
var goodParam = {name :'john',...}; // contains more properties
```

Answer (score 0):

you can inject and use this function instead: $httpParamSerializerJQLike()